# How can I get bold math symbols?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, bold

To make Latin-letter variables bold I can use e.g. `\mathbf{a}`, but while putting Greek letters or symbols such as `\nabla` inside `\mathbf` doesn't cause any errors or warnings, it also doesn't do anything else.

**What is the best way to make bold math symbols, in particular Greek letters and `\nabla`?**

Comment: **warning:**  if the default computer modern fonts are used, the weight of bold lowercase greek will not appear as bold as that of bold lowercase roman, and it isn't. default bold math (`\mathbf`} with computer modern fonts uses the font `cmbx*` which is an extended font. `\boldsymbol` or `bm` use the only `cm` font that is usually available in bold, `cmmib10`, which is not an extended font. thus the bold greek letters are indeed not as "bold" as the roman.

Comment: `bm{x} = [X_1, \dots, X_D]` worked for me! instead of `\bf`. Seems I didn't have to import anything on my overleaf. The issues with `\bf` was that it bolded EVERYTHING inside my `$$` which was too much.

Answer (score 543, accepted):

The [AMS Short Math Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf) recommends the `\boldsymbol` and `\pmb` commands (and suggests that you use the [`bm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm) package for the former to get a more powerful version than provided by [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).

Comment: I would vote for the `bm` package surely!

Comment: It looks like that `\boldsymbol` (from `amsbsy`) is obsolete and `\bm` (package `bm`) should be used ([ref](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/math/amsbsy.pdf)).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, and maybe it's just temporary, but the AMS Short Math Guide link is not working for me.

Comment: @TMM: I noticed that issue a few weeks ago and assumed at the time that it was temporary; I guess it wasn't.  I've contacted the AMS webmaster, and I'll update the link if necessary once I hear back.

Comment: @TMM: It turns out that the link works for me in Safari, but not in Chrome or Firefox, presumably because of different browser security settings related to the fact that it's an ftp link instead of http (I haven't bothered to sort it out yet).  So maybe it's the same issue for you.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the clarification. I only use Chrome (and sometimes Firefox) though, and I suspect the same is true for many Windows users. So if the AMS wants people to use that guide, it would still be nice if they could somehow solve this problem. Anyway, if it gets solved, please tag me and I will remove these comments.

Comment: @TMM barbara beeton tells me AMS is planning to move everything currently on an ftp server to www sometime in the future, and also that eventually an updated version of the short math guide will be posted to ctan.

Comment: _"It looks like that `\boldsymbol` (from amsbsy) is obsolete and `\bm ` (package bm) should be used"_ — Though the poor souls that are using [Mathjax](http://docs.mathjax.org) e.g., in a [Jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/), that implements all of AMS math and none of `bm` will find that they have no alternatives to `\boldsymbol`

Comment: Please add a short summary of the link you provide, eg how to use \bm ? This prevents the answer from being useless when the link is dead (and it is now)

Comment: can you gives us something we can just copy paste?

Comment: @CharlieParker I'm sure you got your answer by now, but for posterity's sake, add `\usepackage{bm}` before the start of your document and then `\bm{the math you want to bold}`

Comment: vote for \boldsymbol\sigma of package \usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: The "boldness" is much more evident with \pmb{} than with \boldsymbol{}

Comment: I would like to mention that currently `\pmb` and `\bf` are the only working commands in markdown (that I am aware of), and `\pmb` works much more nicely than `\bf`.

Answer (score 294):

In my experience, there is no single best way. Therefore Table 582 on page 270 of the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://mirror.ufs.ac.za/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf#subsection.11.5) comes in really handy. (Visited June 4, 2023)

[image: bold math sym]

Comment: ehm [`bm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm) ehm. Can you underline "experience" with facts about problems of `bm`?

Comment: @tohecz No, unfortunately not. I don't have the particular example anymore. I just happened to stumble on this old question and I thought I'd add this list since I did encounter tricky cases where it was helpful to be able to try different approaches. `bm` should surely be the first package to try though. I will add examples where it doesn't work when it ever happens again.

Comment: You can always use \boldsymbol{}, but  this will only work if there exists a bold version of the symbol in the current font.

Comment: In my personal experience, \pmb (the faked bold) is the most universal

Comment: @Szczypawka Most universal ... probably. But also a measure of last resort.

Comment: @Christian How to make bm work in titles (section, article, etc.) ?

Comment: When used in titles (e.g. section title), `\boldmath` and `\mathbf` works. In constrast, `\bm` is giving errors.

Comment: \langle and \rangle don't seem to get any bolder with \bm.

Answer (score 74):

With [`unicode-math`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) you can use `\symbf{<characters>}` which works for both Greek and Latin letters. (In versions of `unicode-math` older than 0.8 the `\symXXX` macros didn't exist, but you could `\mathbf{<characters>}` directly.)

Compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}
% or a different font:
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\( AaBb∇αβγ \) \par
\( \symbf{AaBb∇αβγ} \) \par
\( \symrm{AaBb∇αβγ} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does not work for me. Bold latin symbols appear OK, but greek ones (from nabla onwards) don't show. I have XITS Math font correctly installed on my system (linux), and I compiled this MWE with both `xelatex`and `lualatex`, with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update to my previous comment: I managed to make it work doing the following. 1) Specify math font as \setmathfont{XITS Math} (I'm on a linux system and that is the name of the font my system reports) and 2) Adding \usepackage{bm} AFTER setting the math font. Without step 2), greek bold characters don't show up and latin bold appears to be typeset in Latin Modern Bold

Comment: @OrestesMas There were some updates to `unicode-math` recently, use `\symbf` instead of `\mathbf`.

Comment: neither `\symbf` or `\mathbf` worked for me. `bm` package suggested below works smoothly.

Comment: @relG I guess that could be caused by how you've set up up your document. If you want to know why it didn't work, I suggest posting a new question with a minimal working example.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm not really motivated to do that when there's a simpler option, especially when others have also experienced problems with this solution.

Comment: @relG Of course that's entirely up to you. (The problem mentioned in previous comments were caused by an update to the `unicode-math` package I think, the answer has been updated since. I do see that the [latest version of XITS on CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/xits) doesn't actually have a file called `xits-math.otf`, so I think I'll update the answer with different file names. Apart from that, the code in the answer works fine.)

Answer (score 50):

Another possibility is [`\boldmath`](http://texblog.net/help/latex/boldmath.html), though I would prefer `\boldsymbol` of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) as well. `\unboldmath` switches back to the normal math font.

Comment: Why is `\boldsymbol` preferred over `\boldmath`?

Comment: @drs `\boldsymbol` is included in the package `amsmath`, which is ubiquitous, while `\boldmath` is not.

Comment: I don't know why but `$\boldmath{\phi}$` does not work for me, yet `$\boldsymbol{\phi}$` does.

Comment: @displayname `\boldmath` is a declaration, so you want to use it like this: `{\boldmath $\phi$}`. Also `\(\phi\)` is recommended. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode

Comment: Not sure whats special, but I consistently have issues bolding `\mu` in Overleaf, while other greek characters seem to work with almost all of the suggestions here. `\boldsymbol` is the only function that consistently works across characters I've tried.

Comment: The comment by @glarrain appears to be wrong as `\boldmath` is provided by LaTeX itself (it simply does `\mathversion{bold}`)  so is *always*  available, but must be used outside of math  mode.  And amsmath's `\boldsymbol` is a math-mode only command which exits math mode temporarily to execute `\mathversion{bold}` then re-enters math mode. And limits its action to the duration of its argument.

Answer (score 36):

If you use the package [`bm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm) you can do `$\bm{a}=\bm{\alpha}$` etc.

Answer (score 26):

While `\bm` and `\boldmath` are some good options in LaTeX, modern packages for XeLaTex can give a lot more control over the fonts from the very beginning, without the need to use commands different from the standard `\mathbf` that every one expects naively to work the first time one tries to write bold italic characters.

In XeLaTeX (part of TeXLive), the package `fontspec` gives a lot of freedom when dealing with fonts. If you want even more flexibility for mathematical input, you can try using the package `unicode-math` (that is built on `fontspec`). Nevertheless you will find the \bm and \boldsymbol traditional commands don't work. You can nonetheless specify how you want it to deal with your bold math symbols using an option while loading the `unicode-math` package. `\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}` will give the recommended italic bold math symbols for both greek and latin characters, while `\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}` will give upright latin characters. This is explained in the unicode-math [documentation](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf) .

This minimal working example:

```
%run this with XeLaTeX!!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
%\usepackage[bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}


\begin{document}

This is common math $O(\log n)+O(\lambda,\,\epsilon)$

This is bold and italic $\mathbf{O(\log n)}+\mathbf{O(\lambda,\,\epsilon)}$ where it must :)
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Rather than posting identical answers to different questions, you should post your answer at the most appropriate place (here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104524/510) and (as soon as you have 50 rep) add comments with links at other places.

Answer (score 7):

Use the command `\boldsymbol{YOUR_SYMBOL}`

Comment: this worked for me! thank you

Answer (score 6):

In order to have just one command for both bold text and bold math, one can use the solution suggested on [LaTeX Community](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10866&f=44#p42084). Editing this solution slightly in order to incorporate the `bm` package, one could use the following.

```
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand*{\B}[1]{\ifmmode\bm{#1}\else\textbf{#1}\fi}
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. I would like to point out the following, in case anyone deals with the same situation: I have been using `\mathbf{}` throughout a project only to find out that it does not work with greek letters. I modified your solution to: `\renewcommand*{\mathbf}[1]{\ifmmode\bm{#1}\else\textbf{#1}\fi}` (notice the `renew` rather than `new`) and everything worked perfectly without any other changes.  I am relatively novice with LaTex, so if what I am describing is worthless or trivial or anything, feel free to edit or remove.

Answer (score 4):

My solution (the one that I use) is the `\mathversion{bold}` and `\mathversion{normal}` commands.

This piece of code is not a MWE —however, it shows how to use them:

```
\mathversion{bold}
\section{Behavior of $f$ as a function of $\lambda$}\label{sec:1}
\mathversion{normal}

And now, imagine that \mathversion{bold}\textbf{we want to put some
text in bold, and that this text contains some inline equation such as
$\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}{{p_\mathrm{y}(\lambda=2)}^j}$.}\mathversion{normal}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very good option if you want to enable bold math globally.

Comment: Thank you. I was really looking for a global option

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\boldm}[1] {\mathversion{bold}#1\mathversion{normal}}
\begin{document}

There is a normal symbol, $p_1$. Now, a bold symbol: {\boldm $p_2$}. It works!

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Rendered example of using bold and math in LaTeX]

Comment: $\boldsymbol{x_0}$ was not working for me in either \chapter{title} or \section{title} (but did in \subsection{title}, go figure) but your {\boldm $x_{0}$} saved my day. And no need for any additional package. Totally amazing.

Comment: Just one bit of trouble: $x_{0}$ is now bold in the toc. Oh well.

Comment: These cant’t be nested. Perhaps wrap in a `\mbox`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`physics` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/physics) and write any math symbol in boldface by using command `\vb{}` inside mathmode, e.g. `$\vb{\Psi}$` will yield **Ψ**.

Comment: It doesn't work for lowercase Greek letters.

Answer (score 4):

Observe how ugly `\pmb` is in the following example, compared to `\bm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\begin{document}
$$\Psi_n \pmb{\Psi_n} \bm{\Psi_n} \boldsymbol{\Psi_n} \Psi_n$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the minimal example that works, but in a complicated thesis template, I only get the 2nd type irrespective of the command used. How to identify the conflicting pkg that causes this?

Comment: You need to copy all your code to a new .tex file, then start recursively deleting all the unnecessary text (starting with the rest of the body of your thesis). When you have only one paragraph of writing, start removing the packages, while still compiling the file to check the output. There may be one package that swings it. Feel free to share code at pastebin.com , excluding intellectual property.

Answer (score 3):

The `unicode-math` package supports several commands for bold symbols beyond what have been mentioned in previous answers, including `\mathbf`, `\symbf`, `\symbfup`, `\symbfit` and `\boldsymbol`.  It requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

If you load a math font that has a bold version, `unicode-math` will load it as `version=bold`.  There are now several, including XITS Math, Libertinus Math, and KP Math.  It is also possible to load any math font with `\setmathfont[version=bold]`.

Here’s a brief MWE that uses `\boldmath`, `\symbf` and `\boldsymbol`.  Note that `\mathbf` will use the bold weight of the main text font, `\symbf` will use the mathematical bold letters and numerals defined in the Unicode Mathematical Alphenumeric Characters block, and `\boldmath`, `\mathversion{bold}` and `\boldsymbol` will use the bold math font (if there is one).

```
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures = Common]
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
\section*{\boldmath Reasoning from \(\symbf{A} \vee \symbf{B}\)}

If we have \(\symbf{A} \vee \symbf{B}\) and \(\symbf{A}\), disjunctive syllogism
(classically known as \textbf{\textit{modus ponendo tollens}}, and also known
as \textbf{disjunction elimination} or {\boldmath \(\vee E\)}) is the rule
that lets us conclude \(\boldsymbol\therefore \symbf{B}\).

\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

There are several ways to tweak this behavior.  By default, `\mathbf` renders bold capital letters upright and bold lowercase letters italic, but `[math-style=ISO]` makes italic the default for everything, including regular-weight uppercase Greek.  You can change only the behavior of bold uppercase letters with `bold-style=ISO]` or `[bold-style=upright]`.  You can also specify `\symbfup` for bold upright or `\symbfit` for bold italic.

Comment: Requires LuaLaTeX or XeLateX.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Looking back, I saw some things I said had gotten out of date, so I revised that paragraph. It now mentions LuaTeX and XeTeX, in case someone doesn’t already know.

Comment: Huh, I left out a `\neg` in my example.

Comment: I am getting warnings which (probably) say that the bold font was not found. Can you please look in to this? I am using an updated TeX Live 2022. This is the image link to warnings and the output: https://imgur.com/a/bidrDN9

Comment: For some reason, instead of defining fonts manually, if I use `\usepackage[libertinus]{fontsetup}`, then I get the correct output. (ignoring the mathtools warnings)

Answer (score 0):

Like in some other answers, I use `\mathversion{bold}`, but I've never had to use `\mathversion{normal}` to reset the font. In particular, I use the following commands:

```
\newcommand{\allbf}[1]{\textbf{\mathversion{bold}#1}}
```

to get bold characters for both text and math.

And with the `article` class, to get bold math in addition to the usual bold text in any section title (at any section level):

```
\let\B@startsection\@startsection
\renewcommand{\@startsection}[6]{\B@startsection
{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{\mathversion{bold}#6}}
```