# Bold text and newlines inside equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking, bold

What I'm doing:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

% don't know what some of those do, but i think all the math related ones are
% there
% there are more packages being imported though
```

Then I try:

```
\textbf{w_{n+1}} = \textbf{w_{n}} + e\eta\textbf{x}(n) \\
\textbf{\Delta}\textbf{w} = e\eta\textbf{x}

% above doesn't work, complains about missing $

\textbf{$w_{n+1}$} = \textbf{$w_{n}$} + e\eta\textbf{$x$}(n) \\
\textbf{$\Delta$}\textbf{$w$} = e\eta\textbf{$x$}

% above compiles, but no bold and no newline
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/bold-math-symbols

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could bold an equation with `\boldsymbol`. Use `\align` for multiline equation with alignment.

```
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{w_{n+1}} &= \boldsymbol{w_n} + e\eta\boldsymbol{x}(n) \\
\boldsymbol{\Delta w} &= e\eta\boldsymbol{x}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Tried both \boldsymbol and \boldmath and neither worked. Without the $ it compiles, but then the text isn't bold. And with the $ it doesn't compile.

Comment: @bada: Try to `\usepackage{amsbsy}` — although amsmath already loaded it.

Comment: I added a `\begin{split}` after the `\begin{align}` and an `\end{split}` before the `\end{align}` and it worked the way I wanted.

Comment: try `\(\mathbf{A}\)` inside math environment or `\boldmath\(A\)` before it

Answer (score 22):

`\textbf` is for text mode, not math mode. Also, inline math (`$ ... $`) is for use inline, and so does not produce new lines. This is pretty basic math stuff for TeX: perhaps you should read something like *Math Mode* by Herbert Voss (type `texdoc mathmode` at the Terminal/Command Line).

I think you would be best using the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{w_{n+1}}  &= \mathbf{w_{n}} + e\eta\mathbf{x}(n) \\
  \mathbf{\Delta w} &= e\eta\mathbf{x}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm getting a black square instead of \Delta when I use that. With \delta it's fine though. Do you know how I could fix it? Also, this gives the second line an equation number of its own, which isn't what I need. ;/

Comment: \usepackage{bm}
\bmdefine\bDelta{\Delta}

And then use \bDelta to get a bold \Delta

Answer (score 10):

Use `$\mathbf{w_{n+1}}$`. However, if you want bold symbols, you'd have to use `$\pmb{\eta}$`

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunate that the comment of **Crowley** here above is not more highlighted. 
He give me the answer I search : using `\boldmath` before the eqn environment, all the math portion is in bold font and the text stay normal.

An example of my code:

```
   \boldmath\begin{align*}
    p(X,Y) \Leftrightarrow
                & minimal(X) \\
                & \qquad \wedge directly-solve(X,Y) &&\mbox{ (cas de base)}\\
                & \vee \\
                & \neg minimal(X) \\
                & \qquad \wedge decompose(X,partX,restX) &&\mbox{ (diviser)}\\
                & \qquad \wedge process(partX,part-Y) &&\mbox{ (traitement interne)}\\
                & \qquad \wedge p(restX,restY) &&\mbox{ (appel récursif)}\\
                & \qquad \wedge compose(partY,restY,Y) &&\mbox{ (recomposer)}\\
    \end{align*}
```

Thanks

[image: resultat]