# Bold math: Automatic choice between \mathbf and \boldsymbol for Latin and Greek symbols?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, bold

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/bold-math-symbols).

Suppose you want to denote vectors by **upright bold** letters; then `\mathbf{u}` works fine, except that if it's a Greek letter you have to use `\boldsymbol{\omega}` instead.

**Question**: Is it possible to define a generic vector command in LaTeX which automatically chooses between `\mathbf` and `\boldsymbol`, so that one can write just `\vect{u}` and `\vect{\omega}` without having to treat the Greek symbols specially by hand?

(Just to be clear: `\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}` is no good in this situation, since `\boldsymbol{u}` gives ***bold italic*** instead of roman.)

Comment: \boldsymbol(\omega) -> \boldsymbol{\omega}; I couldn't edit because of some "minimum 6 character" rule...

Comment: @equaeghe: Fixed.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use *both* commands together and define something like

```
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

which should work for most cases.

Answer (score 16):

The macro

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

does not work with mathtime pro lite fonts (and from the comments it appears that it does not work with mathpazo either). Another approach is to simply check if the argument is `A-Za-z`.

```
\usepackage{bm,xstring}

\def\VEC#1%
    {\IfSubStr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}{#1}
        {\mathbf{#1}}
        {\bm{#1}}}
```

This is inefficient since it performs the substring check for each execution. One could define macros `\VEC@A`, `\VEC@B` etc (using a simple loop), and then check do

```
\def\VEC#1%
    {\ifcsname VEC@#1\endcsname
        \mathbf{#1}%
     \else
         \bm{#1}%
     \fi}
```

Answer (score 10):

Although this doesn't answer your question, have you tried using the `bm` package? Then `$\bm{\omega}$` gives a bold omega, `$\bm{u}$` gives a bold (math italic) u, and `$\bm{\mathrm{u}}$` a bold roman u.

Comment: Indeed, defining something like `\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}` would do the trick.

Comment: @Juan: why not make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: Hmm.. because I thought it was pretty much the same (i.e. use *both* commands together), but maybe not?

Comment: @Juan: Thanks, that works! Except that I'm getting weird errors from an \underbrace in a file where I tried it: "Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition." and " LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version bold." Unfortunately that particular formula works fine in a file on its own, so I'm having trouble producing a minimal example where it fails...

Comment: `\newcommand*\vect[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}}` works.

Comment: @TH.: Yes, that works too (with Computer Modern). However, both your suggestion and Juan's fail when used with the mathpazo package... (`\vect{\omega}` gives a bold exclamation mark.)

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: Indeed. I'm afraid I have no insights. Fonts are mysterious to me.

Comment: `\boldsymbol{...}` on its own doesn't seem to do anything (both `\omega` and `u` stay unchanged). And `\mathbf{\omega}` on its own already gives the exclamation mark when using `mathpazo`.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to add: if you want **upright** greek characters, use

```
\usepackage{upgreek}
```

Combining this with the above answers, you can then e.g. do

```
\vect{\upmu}
```

to get a bold upright mu.

(sourced from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106379/151159))