# Upright bold greek with condition in math mode

Tags: etoolbox, greek, xstring

Good day!

I googled the whole stackechange, but was not able to find the answer. I'm quite new to Latex, so my approach is not proper. I try to define a macro, that should format greek letter as **upright bold**. I know there are several ways to do it, I would like to avoid usage of isomath and stick to *upgreek* package.

I want to be able to write

```
\gb{\alpha}
\gb{\Alpha}
```

and in both cases get upright bold characters. So, here is my code inside:

```
\newcommand{\gb}[1]{ % Imagine #1=\Psi
\StrGobbleLeft{\detokenize{#1}}{1}[\chrcodet] % variable "\Psi"
\StrGobbleRight{\chrcodet}{1}[\chrcode] % variable "Psi"
\StrLeft{\chrcode}{1}[\chrfirst] % first character "P"
\IfSubStr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}{\chrfirst} % Is it capital?
    {\boldsymbol{#1}} % Yes - no modification
    {\boldsymbol{\csname up\chrcode\endcsname}} % No - glue \up+Psi (that what happens!)
}
```

I'm trying to get the first character of the control sequence and if it's capital, I call just `\boldsymbol` with no modifications, otherwise I want to modify control sequence by placing `\up` at the beginning. So, when I do that, it produces the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\bm@command ->\upPsi
```

It looks like the "if" condition always gives false, i.e. "P" is not recognized as capital, thus the following MWE will write twice "lowercase":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,upgreek}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\gb}[1]{
    \StrGobbleLeft{\detokenize{#1}}{1}[\chrcodet]
    \StrGobbleRight{\chrcodet}{1}[\chrcode]
    \StrLeft{\chrcode}{1}[\chrfirst]
    #1 - \IfSubStr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}{\chrfirst}{uppercase}{lowercase}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \psi,\Psi,\gb{\psi},\gb{\Psi}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone give me an idea, why it does not work as expected?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does not `bm` just do what you want without any further redefinitions?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,upgreek}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \psi, \uppsi, \Psi,\bm{\psi},\bm{\uppsi},\bm{\Psi}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It does! But I want to try to avoid the explicite usage of `\uppsi` and always write `\psi`.

Comment: @VladimirIvannikov just put `\let\psi\uppsi` in your preamble.

Comment: This instruction will completely replace italic `\psi`, I want to have it italic by default, but upright for bold.

Comment: @VladimirIvannikov You can do it locally `\def\gbm#1{{\let\psi\uppsi
\bm{#1}}}` even if you add all the lowercase greek aliases it's likely to be quicker than detokenising and string comparisons.

Comment: thank you for your help - this solution is really nice, will do it to keep working with my text. But I would also like to understand, why my macro fails at the step I pointed.

Comment: @VladimirIvannikov  aaaaah confused me for a while:-) the detokenize dance that you do produces a `P` of catcode **12** which is not a substring of the catcode 11 A-Z

Comment: wow! :) I had no idea about catcodes! At the end I made it working.

Answer (score 4):

Great thanks to David Carlisle!

It was exactly correct idea about catcodes. Due to lack of experience, I had no idea about catcodes. Making my attempts I was also confused, when I tried **etoolbox** function `\ifstrequal` to compare normal `P` (catcode 11) and detokenized `P` (catcode 12) and it worked! After I decided to take a look inside the source code of the toolbox and I found there `\detokenize` applied to both operands. So I modified my macro in a similar fashion, thus it works as expected now.

Macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm,upgreek}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\gb}[1]{
    \StrGobbleLeft{\detokenize{#1}}{1}[\chrcode]
    \StrGobbleRight{\chrcode}{1}[\chrcode]
    \StrLeft{\chrcode}{1}[\chrfirst]
    \edef\tempa{\detokenize{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}}
    #1 - no\;detokenize: \IfSubStr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}{\chrfirst}{upper}{lower}, \,
    detokenize\;both: \IfSubStr{\tempa}{\chrfirst}{upper}{lower}, \,
    etoolbox: \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\chrfirst}{P}{upper}{lower}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \gb{\psi}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \gb{\Psi}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Maybe, it's not the best solution and I do believe not efficient for the posed problem, but it was useful experience!