# How to write a greek letter as bold and not italic?

Tags: math-mode, bold, greek

How to write the letter θ as bold and not italic?

I have tried the following but it gives me the θ as italics and not bold:

```
\textbf{$\theta$}
```

Comment: bm package \bm{\theta]

Comment: David, the θ is getting bold, but again is Italic. The θ is a vector. So, I want it "lots of bold" and not Italic.

Comment: This question explicitly asks about getting the same behaviour of `\mathbf` has with letters but with greek letters: `\mathbf{a}` gives **a**, the author wants `\greekmathbf{\alpha}` to give **α** rather than ***α***.

Comment: Why the reopen? The OP agreed about the duplicate (when the OP agrees, Community closes). This question asks how to get bold for greek math letters and the linked question answers exactly that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `\textbf` use `\boldsymbol` (load the [amsmath package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to get it) to get it bold, put everything in math mode, and to get it upright use the [upgreek package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/upgreek) and `\uptheta` instead of `theta`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\uptheta}$
\end{document}
```

If you do not need it just for one theta, also see at [Bold math: Automatic choice between \mathbf and \boldsymbol for Latin and Greek symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3535/6865)

Comment: Stephen, what you said, is the same with that David said.
Probably, it is not possible to have a greek letter as a letter of vector.

Comment: Why shouldn't it and what is the problem with the provided solution?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis If you want a vector, I would recommend a command `\vect{\theta}` or `\greekvec{\theta}` or whatever. And you change the behaviour afterwards.

Comment: Stephen, now it's ok. Both you said are accepted. It depends on what someone wants. Thanks.