# How to bold math-mode characters?

Tags: math-mode, bold

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/bold-math-symbols)

I am wondering if it is possible to bold characters under math-mode, for instance, is it possible to bold `$\langle \rangle$`?

Comment: how about `\boldsymbol`?

Comment: Duplicate of [Bold math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/2693)

Comment: It seems to be an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the [bm](http://ctan.org/pkg/bm) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\bm{\langle \rangle}$
\end{document}
```