# Using there exists symbol within inference of the semantic package

Tags: symbols, semantics

I am using the `semantic` package to write inference rules.  I need to put a there exists symbol which is standard to LaTeX using `$\exists$`.  However, when used within the `semantic` package's `inference` command as follows:

```
\inference[case$_0$]{$\exists$ I}{test}
```

several errors are encountered :

```
(./semantics.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
! Missing $ inserted.
&lt;inserted text&gt;
$
l.42 \inference[case$_0$]{$\exists$ I}
{test}
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\@processPremiseLine ...ce \end \hskip \@@pSpace }
\fi \fi \def \sem@tmp {#2}...
l.42 \inference[case$_0$]{$\exists$ I}
{test}
! Missing $ inserted.
&lt;inserted text&gt;
$
l.42 \inference[case$_0$]{$\exists$ I}
{test}
! Missing } inserted.
&lt;inserted text&gt;
}
l.42 \inference[case$_0$]{$\exists$ I}
{test}
[1] (./semantics.aux) )
```

Can anyone suggest what I can do please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "box" the item using `\ensuremath`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semantic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/semantic
\begin{document}
\inference[case$_0$]{\ensuremath{\exists~I}}{test}
\end{document}
```

Note the forced spacing as a result of the tie `~`. This may just be your preference, which I've stuck to.

Comment: How does one get a bold version of \exists, or any other version that would have a stronger look?

Comment: @Maesumi: See [How can I get bold math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/5764)

Answer (score 6):

The mandatory arguments seem to be in mathmode by definition, so you do not need to enter mathmode. Remove the dollar signs and it works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semantic}
\begin{document}
\inference[case$_0$]{\exists I}{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn, I'm too slow ...