# \boldsymbol not working with fontsetup package

Tags: luatex, boldsymbol, fontsetup

How can I get `\boldsymbol` to work when using the [`fontsetup`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontsetup?lang=en) package?

---

LuaLaTeX without `\usepackage{fontsetup}` but with `\usepackage{amsmath}`:

[image]

LuaLaTeX with `\usepackage{fontsetup}`:

[image]

---

I'm using the following code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    $x$ and $\boldsymbol{x}$
\end{document}
```

I've tried loading `amsmath` not at all as well as before an after `fontsetup`, but nothing worked.

---

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(1)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(1)/m/n' instead on input line 5.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(2)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(2)/m/n' instead on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(2)/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.00075pt on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(2)/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.00053pt on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(3)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(3)/m/n' instead on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(3)/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.99925pt on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(3)/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 4.99947pt on input line 5.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./output.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Comment: Welcome to `TeX.SE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\symbfit` command to get bold italic math as defined in Unicode blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    \(x\) and \(\symbfit{x}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: fontsetup_bold_italic_x]

NewCM-Book, the font which `fontsetup` sets by default has all the Greek and Latin uppercase and lowercase serif bold, italic and bold italic characters. You can take a look at [this document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newcomputermodern/doc/newcm-unimath-symbols.pdf) for all the Unicode math available symbols.

New Computer Modern Math does not support math `version=bold` as far as I know. But many characters you probably need are provided. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616018/128462) to see which fonts have `boldmath` coverage.