# How to bold just one word in a line

Tags: fonts, math-mode, bold

If I have a line of text, how do I make just the first word **bold**?

I tried this:

```
\bf{NTn} = Number of lines
```

but it made the entire line bold.

Comment: Use `\textbf{Some text in bold}`.

Comment: Please see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764) regarding the use of font switches.

Comment: `\bf` is an outdated font *switch*, not a macro with an argument, i.e. itr works to the end of the group. You would need to use `{\bf NTn}` instead, but should not use the font commands any longer. Use `\textbf{..}` or `{\bfseries ..}` instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not use `\bf`. Instead use `{\bfseries ....}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


{\bfseries NTn} = Number of lines

$\mathbf{NTn} + \boldsymbol{\pi} + \pmb{\pi} $ = Number of lines.

\verb|\boldsymbol| and \verb|\pmb| are provided by \verb|amsmath| package. Note that \verb|\mathbf| has no effect on symbols like $+$ or $-$ or $\pi$ etc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it is better to use `\bm` from `bm` package for such needs which gives correct results.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I need to bold the following:  $NT_n$ ?   {\bfseries $NT_n$} doesn't work.....

Comment: @ngramsky, for math mode, use `\mathbf{e^{j\pi}=-1}'.

Comment: For bolding math you can use `\boldmath`, `\boldsymbol` or `\pmb`. For mor details see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols)

Comment: @ngramsky: see the edited answer.

Comment: @HarishKumar I stumbled upon this answer and find it ***very*** wrong. For instance `\boldmath` works just by chance and throws warnings; `\boldsymbol` is deprecated and `\bm` (from the `bm` package) should be used.

Comment: @egreg ooow!..... Added a caveat. Thanks for digging.

Comment: @HarishKumar You forgot to remove the wrong `\boldmath` that, by the way, is not a command taking an argument.

Comment: @egreg Yes. Was in the middle of some other work.

Answer (score 11):

For regular, **bold** and *italics* math, use the [`bm` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bm):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bm
\begin{document}
$NTn=\bm{NTn}=\mbox{Number of lines}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

this works for me

```
\textbf{BOLD}
```

Comment: This answer is very short and does not provide some new solution

Comment: Actually, `\textbf` was only mentioned in comments.