# Bold symbols for Greek letters

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols)

I use for bold Greek letters the command `\boldsymbol` for other maths expression `\mathbf`, but the font weight is not the same. How can I get the font weight of bold Greek letters the same as using `\mathbf`?

Comment: [`bm`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/bm) package is useful for bold Greek characters.

Comment: @percusse -- i'm not sure this question is the same as the one pointed out in the reason for closing.  in the example there, the *weight* of the bold lowercase greek *appears* to be not as bold as that of the lowercase roman, and it isn't.  default bold math (`\mathbf`} with computer modern fonts uses the font `cmbx*` which is an *extended* font.  `\boldsymbol` or `bm` use the only `cm` font that is usually available in bold, `cmmib10`, which is *not an extended font*.  thus the bold greek letters are indeed not as "bold" as the roman.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have voted for closing since there is a XeLaTeX answer that I have also used. But my comment is just a suggestion. Nevertheless I can ping the powers that be to reopen the question if you would like to teach me about it.

Comment: @persusse -- using a different font family (which can easily be done with xelatex) would remove the problem.  but it's impossible with the default font complement of computer modern.  i don't necessarily advocate reopening the question, but what might be worth doing is to add an explanatory comment to the cited question.  (i addressed you with the comment since yours was the only one present, and only one "target" is recognized.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton No problem. I've also asked for moderator opinion. But do you know an easy way out with the available standard fonts?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think it was me who initiated the question closure. I checked the other one, and it seemed to me that (1) it mentions greek letters and (2) there are sufficient answers covering greek letters there. I would agree with you that it might be better to address this to the linked question.