# Bold Greek letters are not as bold as Roman letters

Tags: math-mode, greek, boldmath

This question was discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68841/96172) previously, but no answer is provided.

Greek letters are made bold using `\boldsymbol`, however they do not look bold at all compared to bold Roman letters, particularly they are within the text and if the text is also Roman.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[]{bm}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Bold Roman: $\textbf{M}$, $\textbf{a}$, $xyz$. These look OK.\\
Bold Greek: $\boldsymbol{\uppsi}xyz\boldsymbol{\psi}$. They do not look bold at all.
\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

Also consider the default font:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[]{bm}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Bold Roman: $\textbf{M}$, $\textbf{a}$, $xyz$. These look OK.\\
Bold Greek: $\boldsymbol{\uppsi}xyz\boldsymbol{\psi}$. These are a little bit better but still not bold.
\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

**Edit:**

Here is an example text to see the characters better. To me, Roman characters are immediately catching the eye as bold, but not the Greek letters:

[image]

Is there a way to have "real" bold Greek letters?

**Edit (based on David's comments):**

Use of `\pmb` with Roman text (second line):

[image]

Use of `\pmb` with default text (second line):

[image]

**Edit:**

I have added Troys suggestion below. I think this look gives immeadiate impression of a matrix.

[image]

Comment: they look quite bold to me, in any case it is the choice of the font designer to design how dark the bold face is compared to medium weight. You can not change this from tex other than by choosing a different font family that has a bolder bold.

Comment: Maybe: double print the Greek letter with a shift? Is there a way to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: yes sure the `\pmb` macro in amsmath will print the character 3 times with slight offsets but I'd never do that of (as here) there is a bold font available.

Comment: for example if you extend your example with `\uppsi` and `\psi` then the newtxmath one looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttsGB.png) with the bold characters noticeably bolder than the non bold despite the following text saying they do not look bold.

Comment: @David: No wonder  you do not recommend \pmb. See my updated question :).

Comment: Bold letters are used for matrices and it really makes a big difference  if a variable is understood as a matrix clearly. I added a portion from my text, where it is really difficult to make the distinction immediately.  Anyhow...

Comment: You can try adapting [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383798/117534) for `\psi` and see if it is acceptable.

Comment: @Troy: I think your solution help a lot. Hope there is no downside of using it. If you make an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice solution adapted from [another question:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383324/bold-checkmark/383798#383798)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\newcommand*{\boldgreek}[1]{%
  \textpdfrender{%
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,%
    LineWidth=.35pt,%
  }{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
  $\psi$
  $\boldgreek{\psi}$
  $\uppsi$
  $\boldgreek{\uppsi}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can modify the line width to your liking to make the letters more/less bold.