# bold version of succcurlyeq?

Tags: bold, amssymb, bm

I would like to find a free font (preferably as in free speech) that can be used with LaTeX and that contains a bold version of `$\succcurlyeq$` (defined in package `amssymb`).

Currently I use poor man’s bold, but it is unsatisfactory, especially as the bold version of `$\succcurlyeq$` differs from the normal `$\succcurlyeq$` in a different way than the bold version of `$\succeq$` differs from the normal `$\succeq$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\succ$ $\boldsymbol{\succ}$
$\succeq$ $\boldsymbol{\succeq}$
$\succcurlyeq$ $\boldsymbol{\succcurlyeq}$
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

More generally, is there somewhere a list of fonts “compatible” with LaTeX? (As I understand, not every font can be used with LaTeX, under the constraint of sticking to LaTeX rather than switching to XeLaTeX or Lua.) And is there a way of searching specifically for a font that contains bold symbols?

Comment: You could use a screenshot (of your pdf) in order to make clear what you mean.

Comment: You can use the same technique here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405446/117534

Comment: Thanks for the edit (and the advice)! I just thought about using http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/, which I was about to do.

Comment: ` MnSymbol` has a bold version.  You might import only the bold  version of this character.

Comment: See [Level of "boldness" changeable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27843/5764)

Comment: I’m most interested by a real font that would provide the symbols I need (in normal and bold version). Other tricks to tweak the level of boldness might be interesting as a workaround if the first option does not exist.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the reference to MnSymbol. That looks promising. Can you please tell me how I can use only some specific symbols from that font, without changing the fonts used in the rest of the document? The MnSymbol manual only mentions how to globally load the font, if I read correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately the AMS symbol fonts don't provide a bold version. The `mathabx` version is mostly compatible with CM, other symbol fonts have quite different symbols.

Comment: @egreg: I don't think `mathabx` has a bold version.

Comment: @Troy I didn’t manage to make \textpdfrender render correctly with superscripts, which I need. E.g. \textpdfrender{TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,LineWidth=.35pt}{\succcurlyeq}^\textbf{r} does not render nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AMS symbol fonts don't provide bold versions and neither do the `mathabx` fonts.

You can use the symbols in `MnSymbol`, but they're smaller than the CM fonts; scaling them will thicken their strokes. Here's an experiment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolD}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolD5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolD6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolD7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolD8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolD9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolD10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolD12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolD-Bold5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolD-Bold6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolD-Bold7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolD-Bold8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolD-Bold9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolD-Bold10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolD-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyD}{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyD}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol\prec{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"68}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succ{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"69}
\DeclareMathSymbol\preceq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6A}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succeq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6B}
\DeclareMathSymbol\preccurlyeq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6C}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succcurlyeq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6D}
\DeclareMathSymbol\precsim{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6E}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succsim{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6F}
\DeclareMathSymbol\precapprox{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"70}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succapprox{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"71}

\begin{document}

$\prec\succ\preceq\succeq\preccurlyeq\succcurlyeq\precsim\succsim$
$<>$

\mathversion{bold}

$\prec\succ\preceq\succeq\preccurlyeq\succcurlyeq\precsim\succsim$
$<>$

\end{document}
```

[image]

At natural size (with `[1.0]` or removing `s*[1.2]` altogether)

[image]

With also negated symbols (at natural size)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolD}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolD5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolD6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolD7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolD8
   <9-10> MnSymbolD9
  <10-12> MnSymbolD10
  <12->   MnSymbolD12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolD-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolD-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolD-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolD-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolD-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolD-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolD-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyD}{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyD}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol\prec{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"68}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succ{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"69}
\DeclareMathSymbol\preceq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6A}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succeq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6B}
\DeclareMathSymbol\preccurlyeq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6C}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succcurlyeq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6D}
\DeclareMathSymbol\precsim{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6E}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succsim{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"6F}
\DeclareMathSymbol\precapprox{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"70}
\DeclareMathSymbol\succapprox{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"71}
\DeclareMathSymbol\nprec{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E0}
\DeclareMathSymbol\nsucc{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E1}
\DeclareMathSymbol\npreceq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E2}
\DeclareMathSymbol\nsucceq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E3}
\DeclareMathSymbol\npreccurlyeq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E4}
\DeclareMathSymbol\nsucccurlyeq{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E5}
\DeclareMathSymbol\nprecsim{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E6}
\DeclareMathSymbol\nsuccsim{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E7}
\DeclareMathSymbol\nprecapprox{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E8}
\DeclareMathSymbol\nsuccapprox{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{"E9}

\begin{document}

$\prec\succ\preceq\succeq\preccurlyeq\succcurlyeq\precsim\succsim$
$<>$

$\nprec\nsucc\npreceq\nsucceq\npreccurlyeq\nsucccurlyeq\nprecsim\nsuccsim$

\mathversion{bold}

$\prec\succ\preceq\succeq\preccurlyeq\succcurlyeq\precsim\succsim$
$<>$

$\nprec\nsucc\npreceq\nsucceq\npreccurlyeq\nsucccurlyeq\nprecsim\nsuccsim$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the code number of the glyphs? Each time I needed it, I had to count its rank in the doc.

Comment: @Bernard `latexdef -p MnSymbol prec` shows `\prec: \mathchar"3768` The other symbols follow immediately.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for the tip (e Buon Natale!).

Comment: Impressive, as usual. However there’s a problem of baseline, it seems. Try $x \succ y$: the symbol looks too high above the line, especially with 1.2 size. Maybe it’s just a matter of habit?

Comment: @OlivierCailloux Yes, with the 1.2 magnification, the vertex is above the formula axis. It *could* be (inefficiently) fixed, but in my opinion the heavy strokes disqualify this solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use the option fontsize=14pt from KOMA. This makes the 1.0 size much too small compared to the text, I think. Apart from that, do you have any clue about the more general question at the end of my question? (Is there some way to know whether some other font out there has those bold symbols, or whether I should rather give up and stick to poor man’s bold?)