# How do I make the \min and max bold?

Tags: formatting, amsmath, bold, math-operators

Refering to this question
[How to make the table fit into the column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82528/how-to-make-the-table-fit-into-the-column/82529#comment176725_82529)

How should I make the `\min` and `\max` bold?

Answer (score 10):

You could use `\boldmin` defined as `\newcommand\boldmin{\mathop{\mathbf{min}}`

Comment: Or of course `\DeclareMathOperator\boldmin{\mathbf{min}}`

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways for getting bold in math, e.g. see
["How can I get bold math symbols?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols).

Since you have tagged the question with `amsmath`, I assume this package is loaded and then `\boldsymbol` is available. The following example shows some ways to bold an expression with `\min` with different bold ranges:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \min_{i=1}^n q(s_i) \]
\[ \mathop{\boldsymbol\min}_{i=1}^n q(s_i) \]
\[ \mathop{\boldsymbol{\min_{i=1}^n}} q(s_i) \]
\[ \boldsymbol{\min_{i=1}^n q(s_i)} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Bold math can be obtained by loading the `bm` package,  and then using `\bm{\min}` and `\bm{\max}`

Comment: I'm not sure, but does this preserve the correct spacing?

Comment: @tohecz Yes, it does preserve the correct spacing.