# \mathbf not bolding mathematical character

Tags: bold

Why is it that when I type the following:

```
$\mathbf{\mu}$
```

the mu is not bolded?

Consider this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\title{Test}
\author{Test}
\date{}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle

$\mathbf{\mu}$

\end{document}
```

The mu is not bolded. I am using TeXWorks.

Comment: Try `\usepackage{bm}` and `$\bm{\mu}$`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/35864.