# How Can I get bold math symbols into a glossary?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, glossaries, bold

I'd like to add a mathematical Expression to my glossary:

```
\newglossaryentry{Fst}{
  name        = {$F_{st}$-value},
  description = {Inbreeding coefficient,...},
  sort        = {fst}
}
```

Unfortunately, the Expression is not written in bold letters. According to [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols) I tried:

```
\newglossaryentry{Fst}{
  name        = {$\bm{F_{st}}$-value},
  description = {Inbreeding coefficient,...},
  sort        = {fst}
}
```

But this writes Fst in bold letters not only in the glossary, but also in the main text (while `-value` is in bold letters in the glossary, and in normal letters in the text).

Is there a way to add mathematical formulas to the glossary in bold letters, and to the main text in normal letters?

Comment: Using `\boldmath` before `\printglossary`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I have some other formulas within the glossary, which should be normal. Only the name of the glossary entry should be in bold face, and only if its within the "glossary-start" and not when its linked within the text of another glossary entry.

Comment: Please, add a small, but *complete* example. We can't know what you want to have in your glossary, can we?

Comment: I understand that you want glossary terms to be in bold, but I would be very wary of defining a term in bold that isn't bold where it's used, because bold changes the meaning in maths. Here's  a common example: *r* is a radius, **r** is a position vector.

Comment: You could try using the `text` key for the non-bold version and have the bold version in the `name` key, or you can remove the math shift from the `name` key and define a custom style that puts the name in math bold.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Could you please write an answer out of your comment, so that I can accept it. It worked fine. I also added an entry to my blog discussing your solution step by step (in german): http://fenon.de/mathematische-formeln-in-glossar-eintraegen-verwenden/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `text` key if you want a different display in the document text to that shown in the glossaries. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Fst}{
  name        = {$\boldsymbol F_{st}$-value},
  text        = {$F_{st}$-value},
  description = {Inbreeding coefficient,...},
  sort        = {fst}
}

\begin{document}

In document text: \gls{Fst}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]