# Increase font size and making a boldface in mathmode in Latex

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

[image]

How to increase the font size and make a boldface of the whole symbol given above in mathmode in Latex ?

Comment: The whole thing? Or just `\sigma`? And which part do you want to increase the font size of? Please be more specific...

Comment: Would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/34618

Comment: @Werner I need for the whole thing. Edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\bm` command from `bm` package and `\scalebox` from `graphicx` package.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\centering

Normal
\[\sigma_{E_{1}}^{(l)}\]

\bigskip

Bold
\[\bm{\sigma_{E_{1}}^{(l)}}\]

\bigskip

Bold and bigger
\[\scalebox{2}{\ensuremath{\bm{\sigma_{E_{1}}^{(l)}}}}\]

\end{document}
```

The latter can be used outside math mode, as well. Adjust the factor `2` to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative without 'scalebox'.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}

Normal
\[
\sigma^{(l)}_{E_1}
\]

Bold and Huge size
\[
\Huge
\bm{
\sigma^{(l)}_{E_1}}
\]

Bold and scripsize
\[
\scriptsize
\bm{
\sigma^{(l)}_{E_1}}
\]
\end{document}
```