# Bold math in the title of an article

Tags: math-mode, titles, bold

Can this be done? I can't find anything anywhere on this -- which is very strange to me!

Comment: Related: [How can I get bold math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/5764)

Comment: Is there some particular issue with getting this to work in the title specifically? Please post a Minimal (non-)Working Example if Werner's link doesn't answer your question.

Comment: since the distinction between lightface and bold often has a meaning distinction in math, at least some math publishers reject the use of bold math in a title if it isn't also bold in the text.

Comment: Please, seperate questions and answers. It would be best if you (1) specified what style file you use  (including MWE) and then (2) posted the whole addendum as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{$e=mc^2$ in bold}

\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand\maketitle{{\bfseries\boldmath\oldmaketitle}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

$e=mc^2 $

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found `\boldmath` helpful for section tiltles. E.g.: `\section{\boldmath $e=mc^2$ in bold}`. Thank you.

Comment: @CyriacAntony you should not use `\boldmath` in the argument, rather use it where `\bfseries` is used in the declaration of the section style. Using formating in titles is bad style in genral but specifically here the markup you suggest would make the math bold in tables of contents and page running heads, even though the text in those places is not bold.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Is it okay to use `\section[sec tilte in toc & running head]{Usual title}`? (it looks good to me; but I may not be aware of pitfalls).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using a particular .sty file: `imsart`. After the modification, it works well for me now, so thank you everyone for the hints. I have replaced

```
\setattribute{title}      {size} {\LARGE\bfseries}
```

there by

```
\setattribute{title}      {size} {\LARGE\bfseries\boldmath}
```

and it works now.