# How to define vectors when used in equation

Tags: equations, amsmath, bold, greek, vector

So in short I want to have something that looks like this:

[image]

So far I managed to get to the following output:

[image]

[image]
with the code as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
R_{it} = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i} R_{mt} + \varepsilon_{it} \\
E(\varepsilon_{it} = 0) \qquad \var(\varepsilon_{it}) = \sigma_{\varepsilon_{it}}^2
\end{gathered}
\label{eq: marketmodel}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec{R}_i = \vec{X}_i\vec{\theta}_i + \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}_{it}
\label{eq: mmvectors}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{R}_i = [R_{iT_0} \dotsm R_{iT_1}]'$ is an $(L_1 x 1)$ vector of estimation-window returns, 

\end{document}
```

Note please that especially my in-text definition of the variables in the equation are messed up. Also further help for the following equations (4.4.3 - 4.4.6) would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that a `\tau` (a stopping time), not `t`, in the subscript to `R`?

Comment: Don't use `\mathbf` (for `\vec`), but `\boldsymbol` instead. See [How can I get **bold** math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/5764)

Comment: Better use `\usepackage{bm}` and `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}` for example

Comment: @Werner (and Harish) the image shows bold roman for vec R (so \mathbf rather than \boldsymbol or \bm, but then somewhat inconsistently uses bold italic greek so \bm{\theta}

Comment: @A.Ellett - Actually, `t` is much more natural than `\tau`. It's an application of the Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM) -- no stopping time arguments arise. The only reason I can think why the book's author is using `\tau` is because of a possible distinction between "event time" (denoted by `\tau`, I gather) and "calendar time", which presumably would be denoted by `t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't read the image very well. This uses `bm` and `\tau`. I've also replaced `x` with `\times`. I've also added some potentially useful packages - remove any you don't want. I've used Latin Modern just for the example because `mathdesign` didn't display well in my viewer with the default settings and I didn't want to mess around with it.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm,amsfonts,amssymb,lmodern}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
% \usepackage{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
      R_{i\tau} = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i} R_{m\tau} + \epsilon_{i\tau} \\
      E(\epsilon_{i\tau} = 0) \qquad \var(\epsilon_{i\tau}) = \sigma_{\epsilon_{i\tau}}^2
    \end{gathered}
    \label{eq: marketmodel}
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
    \vec{R}_i = \vec{X}_i\vec{\theta}_i + \vec{\epsilon}_{i\tau}
    \label{eq: mmvectors}
  \end{equation}
  where $\vec{R}_i = [R_{iT_{0+1}} \dotsm R_{iT_1}]'$ is an $(L_1 \times 1)$ vector of estimation-window returns,

  \begin{align}
    \vec{\hat{\theta}}_i &= (\vec{X}_i'\vec{X}_i)^{-1} \vec{X}_i'\vec{R}_i\\
    {\hat{\sigma}}^2_{\vec{\epsilon}_i} &= \frac{1}{L_1 - 2} \hat{\vec{\epsilon}}_i'\hat{\vec{\epsilon}}_i\\
    \hat{\vec{\epsilon}}_i &= \vec{R}_i - \vec{X_i}\vec{\hat{\theta}}_i\\
    \var[\vec{\hat{\theta}}_i] &= (\vec{X}_i'\vec{X}_i)^{-1}\sigma^2_{\vec{\epsilon}_i}
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: equations]

Comment: anybody knows what the first symbol in the definion of X_i is???

Comment: @marinko Is it `$\ell$`?

Comment: ... found out it is \iota, if that's a help for anybody

Answer (score 5):

You are better off with `bm` package and

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
R_{i\tau} = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i} R_{m\tau} + \varepsilon_{i\tau} \\
E(\varepsilon_{i\tau} = 0) \qquad \var(\varepsilon_{i\tau}) = \sigma_{\varepsilon_{i\tau}}^2
\end{gathered}
\label{eq: marketmodel}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec{R}_i = \vec{X}_i\vec{\theta}_i + \boldsymbol{\vec{\varepsilon}}_{i\tau}
\label{eq: mmvectors}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{R}_i = [R_{iT_0} \dotsm R_{iT_1}]'$ is an $(L_1 x 1)$ vector of estimation-window returns,
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have replaced `t` with `\tau`, revert if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

the image shows a rather inconsistent font choice using bold upright roman and bold slanted greek for vectors. Perhaps the simplest way to achieve that is using `bm` package and

```
\newcommand\vec[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}
```

then `\vec{R}` and `\vec{\theta}`  should do the right thing