# Correct usage of \mathbf

Tags: math-mode, bold

In my work I have:

```
J_{\mathbf{\lambda}}(f(\mathbf{p},t))
```

but pdflatex prited
[image]

Why? Maybe I'm not using `mathbf` correctly?

Comment: See if [How can I get bold math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595) helps.

Comment: (1) Alway post full minimal examples so we know which packages you are using. (2) It is advisable to use the `bm` package and its `\bm` command instead of `\mathbf` as it *will* give you bold sy,bols which `mathbf` does not.