# Bold brackets in equations

Tags: equations, bold, brackets

I want to write an equation with bold extended brackets.

For instance in:

```
\left[ \frac{1}{2} \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v} \right]
```

I want `\left[` and `\right]` to be bold. I already tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99286/15659 nothing is doing the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best solution I could found:

```
\pmb{\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}\right.}
\frac{1}{2} \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v}
\pmb{\left.\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}\right]}
```

It is dirty, but it does exactly what I want:

[image]

Comment: You can define a macro to handle the phantom automatically by defining it as: \pmb{\left[\vphantom{#1}\right.}
#1
\pmb{\left.\vphantom{#1}\right]}

Answer (score 5):

You can do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

$[ \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v} ]$

$\bm{[} \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v} \bm{]}$

\end{document}
```

It does not work with `\left`, `\right` with the default cm fonts as there is no bold extension font (for large brackets) in that font set. However extended brackets are not needed here.

Comment: The example is bad. I need extended brackets actually.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker cm doesn't have bold extended, so you need to switch fonts or accept they are not bold (or resort to some fake bold over-printing horror:-)

Comment: why the downvote? The answer is correct to report cm doesn't have a bold font for this, "don't shoot the messenger" :-)