# bold version of \right|

Tags: math-mode, bold

I want to have a `\left.\right|` in a mathematical formula in a bold format (just the | line should be bolded, not the entire formula) and I didn't find a way. Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$f(a,\left.\{b\}\right|c)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bold brackets in equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238676/bold-brackets-in-equations)

Comment: @magula it's style does not change by `\bm` at all.

Comment: @CLAUDE: Here is the difference without/with `\bm`: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJXVs.png) The "style" does change. Not sure whether it's sufficient for your needs though. You may have to add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}{ <-> cmexb10 }{}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{boldsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\boldvert}{\mathord}{boldsymbols}{"6A}{boldlargesymbols}{"0C}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
f(a,\left.\{b\}\right\boldvert c)\\
\frac{a}{b}\Big\boldvert
\left.\frac{a}{b}\right\boldvert\\
f(a,\left.\{b\}\right| c)\\
\frac{a}{b}\Big|
\left.\frac{a}{b}\right|
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]