# Error: Missing $

Tags: math-mode, errors

I have

```
bla $ H $ bla bla $ 2 \times 2 $ . blabla:
\begin{equation}
H = \theta \textbf{I} + \textbf{ \tau } \cdot \textbf{a},
\end{equation}
```

Why does it give me the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.206 H = \theta \textbf{I} + \textbf{ \tau }
\cdot \textbf{a},
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\textbf{\tau}` is wrong. It should be `\bm{\tau}` (and you need `\usepackage{bm}`. Also `\textbf{I}` and `\textbf{a}` should be `\mathbf{I}` and `\mathbf{a}`.

Comment: Check this.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols