# Tikz \pmb results in 2 overlapping letters

Tags: equations, bold

For some reason, there seem to be 2 overlapped images of letters inside \pmb{} of the tikz draw feature. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
    \draw (0,0) node {$\pmb{B}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I didn't notice it at first, but if you zoom in, you can see two of the same letter overlapped.. Any idea how to make only one bold letter appear? Any help or work-arounds are appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to do with TikZ, try `$\pmb{B}$` outside the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: See [How can I get bold math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595)/ For latin letters use  `\mathbf{...}`.

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to accept the posted answer. Makes sense.

Comment: How about non-italic bold?

Comment: Well, I deleted the answer because I realized it didn't actually answer your question about how to not get the double-letter effect, it only said *why* that effect occurs. Then I remembered the question I linked to above, which is more comprehensive.

Comment: Oh, shoot! Did you and @TorbjørnT. agree this was a duplicate? I didn't realise my voting to close would just close it immediately. (I am pretty sure you are both saying it is a duplicate but I'm not *that* sure.)

Comment: The other post answers my question, so yeah, that's fine.