# How do I add a newcommand which includes formatting?

Tags: macros

Currently I'm using `\newcommand{\ps}{\textbf{\psi}}` but this bolds everything after `$\ps$`. What do I do to get the desired result of inserting a bold `$\psi$` when I use `$\ps$` ?

Thanks

Comment: You code is not giving bold `\psi` for me. This is how to get a bold symbol: `\newcommand{\ps}{\ensuremath{\pmb{\psi}}}` where the `\pmb` command needs `\usepackage{amsmath}`. Read this question for how to get bold math symbols: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making math symbols bold, it is better to use `bm` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand*{\ps}{\bm{\psi}}
\begin{document}
  \[\alpha \ps \psi \beta\]
  $\ps$ is some bold symbol inlike $\psi$.
\end{document}
```

[image]