# pgfplotstable: how to change the color/font/background of a single cell?

Tags: pgfplotstable, colortbl

Let's look at this MWE, where I am trying to change the formatting/background of a cell in the table. I *think* I have just copied the example in the manual, but I have the nasty effect that the content of the cell is "disturbed":

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

```
% vim: set spelllang=en :
\documentclass{article}

%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\krypt}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{K}r}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs, colortbl}

\pgfplotstableread{
    kr  Rreal   Rlin    deltaR
    0   138.16  143     -4.84
    1   154.18  159.8   -5.62
    2   195.01  176.6   18.41
    3   202.82  193.4   9.42
    4   205.55  210.2   -4.65
}{\fitR}

\begin{document}

With the "single cell" changes: 

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[zerofill, dec sep align,
        %begin table={\begin{tabular}[b]},
        columns/kr/.style={precision=1, column name={Kryptorad (\si{\krypt})}},
        columns/Rreal/.style={precision=2, column name={$R(c)$ (real) (\si{k\ohm})}},
        columns/Rlin/.style={precision=2, column name={$R(c)$ (lin) (\si{k\ohm})}},
        columns/deltaR/.style={precision=2, column name={$\epsilon_\mathrm{abs}$ (lin) (\si{k\ohm})}},
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        every row 2 column 3/.style={
            % stupid example for multiple postprocessors:
            postproc cell content/.append style={
                /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{red!10!white}}{},
            }
        },
        every row 3 column 3/.style={postproc cell content/.style=
            {@cell content=\textbf{##1}}}
    ]{\fitR}

    Without: 

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[zerofill, dec sep align,
        %begin table={\begin{tabular}[b]},
        columns/kr/.style={precision=1, column name={Kryptorad (\si{\krypt})}},
        columns/Rreal/.style={precision=2, column name={$R(c)$ (real) (\si{k\ohm})}},
        columns/Rlin/.style={precision=2, column name={$R(c)$ (lin) (\si{k\ohm})}},
        columns/deltaR/.style={precision=2, column name={$\epsilon_\mathrm{abs}$ (lin) (\si{k\ohm})}},
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    ]{\fitR}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are overwriting the cell content for two columns (dec sep align is active).

Comment: @percusse Aaaaargh... ok, gotcha. Now --- is it solvable maintaining the nice alignment? Thanks!

Comment: It is but pretty tedious as far as I remember. Also Christian is not hopeful either here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276395/pgfplotstable-formatting-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [instrinsic problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276395/pgfplotstable-formatting-problems) of mixing the `dec sep align` option with single-cell property, I found this solution/workaround:

- switching the `dec sep align` off,
- changing the column to `r` type,
- using `fixed`

Code:

```
 \pgfplotstabletypeset[zerofill, 
    %dec sep align,
    columns/kr/.style={precision=1, column name={Kryptorad (\si{\krypt})}},
    columns/Rreal/.style={precision=2, column name={$R(c)$ (real) (\si{k\ohm})}},
    columns/Rlin/.style={precision=2, column name={$R(c)$ (lin) (\si{k\ohm})}},
    columns/deltaR/.style={precision=2, column name={$\epsilon_\mathrm{abs}$ (lin) (\si{k\ohm})},
        column type={r}, fixed},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every row 2 column 3/.style={
        % stupid example for multiple postprocessors:
        postproc cell content/.append style={
            /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{red!10!white}}{},
        }
    },
    every row 3 column 3/.style={postproc cell content/.style=
        {@cell content=\textbf{##1}}}
]{\fitR}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Resulting table]

Comment: To my future self: `\usepackage{colortbl}`