# How to change the color background of a single cell in the last row

Tags: pgfplotstable, colortbl

Using pgfplotstable, I want to color singular cells in the last row of an automatically created table based on csv-input. Since the length of the table differs, I need to color the last cell dynamically.

I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296599/pgfplotstable-how-to-change-the-color-font-background-of-a-single-cell), which is very close to what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm only struggling at this code line:

```
 every row 2 column 3/.style={
 ...
```

Is there a way of inserting the number of the rows while in `\pgfplotstabletypeset` resulting in something like this?

```
every row LAST column 3/.style={
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the formatting to the column description via:

```
postproc cell content/.append code={\ifnum\numexpr\pgfplotstablerow+1=\pgfplotstablerows %
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{red!10!white}}{}}\fi}
```

The crucial variable being `\pgfplotstablerows` which stores the total number of rows.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\krypt}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{K}r}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs, colortbl}

\pgfplotstableread{
    kr  Rreal   Rlin    deltaR
    0   138.16  143     -4.84
    1   154.18  159.8   -5.62
    2   195.01  176.6   18.41
    3   202.82  193.4   9.42
    4   205.55  210.2   -4.65
}{\fitR}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[zerofill, 
    %dec sep align,
    columns/kr/.style={precision=1, column name={Kryptorad (\si{\krypt})}},
    columns/Rreal/.style={precision=2, column name={$R(c)$ (real) (\si{k\ohm})}},
    columns/Rlin/.style={precision=2, column name={$R(c)$ (lin) (\si{k\ohm})}},
    columns/deltaR/.style={precision=2, column name={$\epsilon_\mathrm{abs}$ (lin) (\si{k\ohm})},
    column type={r}, fixed,
    postproc cell content/.append code={\ifnum\numexpr\pgfplotstablerow+1=\pgfplotstablerows %
    \pgfkeys{/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{red!10!white}}{}}\fi}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{\fitR}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a try as soon as I'm in front of my working desktop. From simple scanning I can't determine, how the column which is colored is defined? As far as I understand your code, only the last row/last col is colored?

Comment: I just now understood, that one can postproc the last cell in each column via the abovementioned solution, so the question is answered, case closed.