# How to make formula bold in the title of the chapter and the sections

Tags: bold

I have the following document. I would like that all formula in the title of the sections and the chapters becomes bold (that is ${2\neq}$ and $\nu\geqslant 1$). How to make this possible?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0\baselineskip}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}


\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial} 
\setdigitfont{Arial}

\usepackage{bm, amsbsy}
\usepackage{relsize}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\centersmaller}[1]{%
  \raisebox{.5\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`T-\height}{\smaller[3]#1}}



\begin{document}

\chapter{\centersmaller{(${2\neq}$)}}



\section{$\nu\geqslant 1$}

$\bm{\geqslant}$\\
$\pmb{\geqslant}$
\end{document}
```

I tried to use the suggestions in the link provided in the comment below. The only working solution from there was to use `\pmb` from `bm` packages. Unfortunately using this gives undesirable output for `\gesqlant` as shown in the below image:

[image]

Comment: the methods given here should work: [How can I get bold math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595) (potential duplicate).  but ... think before you do it.  boldness adds different meaning to many symbols.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I edited my question.

Comment: sorry, i can't test this because i don't have access to the tahoma font. (i'm working on a linux machine at my workplace.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I changed Tahoma to Arial (I hope you have it on your system). I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$\bm{formula}$
```

This seems to be working for me, but with pdflatex

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0\baselineskip}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}


\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{bm, amsbsy}
\usepackage{relsize}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\centersmaller}[1]{%
    \raisebox{.5\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`T-\height}{\smaller[3]#1}}



\begin{document}

    \chapter{\centersmaller{(${2\neq}$)}}



    \section{$\nu\geqslant 1$}

    $\bm{\geqslant}$\\
    $\pmb{\geqslant}$


    \chapter{\centersmaller{($\bm{2\neq 2}$)}}


    \section{$\nu\geqslant 1$}

    $\bm{\geqslant}$\\
    $\pmb{\geqslant}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the particularity of my document, I should compile with xelatex. But even with pdfkatex, If you zoom in  you see that the shape of \geqslants' is the same as the image I have attached. So the issue is still there.