# Bolding an item of a list

Tags: math-mode, symbols, enumitem, bold

How would I bold just this item? Thank you.

```
\item $\neg f\to (\neg b\lor\neg m)$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which type of list is it?

Comment: @Bernard I don't think that matters: the math is not an argument to `\item`.

Comment: Related: [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/123129)

Comment: @clemens: depends on whether it's the label of the contents which has to be boldened. It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bolden the contents of the item, the simplest is this:

```
\item \boldmath$\neg f\to (\neg b\lor\neg m)$\unboldmath
```

or, following egreg's suggestion:

```
\item {\boldmath$\neg f\to (\neg b\lor\neg m)$},
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `\item {\boldmath$...$}` is better, IMO.

Comment: @egreg: What's the difference? I thought it was equivalent.

Comment: @Bernard Maybe not equivalent, if `\boldmath` was already in effect. It's conceptual, rather than specific for the case. Use grouping to limit a scope whenever possible.

Comment: OK. Initially, I chose what I posted (\bold ... \unbold) because it's too easy to forget closing a brace, and it's tough to find where it's messing at times. (wonderful slip (and metalepsis): ‘messing’ for ‘missing’!)