# How do I write this table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I want to construct the table from page 8 from [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.0581.pdf):

[image]

I tried this

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{}c|cccc@{}}
\textbf{w^2}-xz & -x & y & 0 & -z & 0 & -z^2+wz \\
 \textbf{wx}-yz & \textbf{w} & -x & -y & 0 & z & z^2 \\
\textbf{x^2}-wy & -z & \textbf{w} & 0 & -y & 0 & 0 \\
\textbf{xy}-z^2 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{w} & \textbf{x} & -y & yz \\
\textbf{y^2}-wz & 0 & 0 & -z & -w & \textbf{x} \textbf{w^2} \\ \hline
    & 0 &  y & -x & textbf{w} & -z & 1 \\
    & -y^2+wz & z^2 & -wy  & yz & -w^2 & \textbf{x}\\
\end{array}$
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}\\
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable and explain what "does not work" mean!

Comment: You want `\mathbf{w}^2`

Comment: You can find more ways on bold math here For more ways see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some errors in the code of the question:

- Two columns are missing in the column specification of `array`.
- `textbf` without backslash
- Missing `&` at the end of the fifth row.
- Bold in math for letters are done with `\mathbf`.
- Exponents are usually *not* made bold.
- `\\` after `\end{table}` is bad style, since `table` is usually a *floating* object, where `\\` does not make any sense, if the object before is floated away.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  $\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
    \mathbf{w}^2-xz & -x & y & 0 & -z & 0 & -z^2+wz \\
    \mathbf{wx}-yz & \mathbf{w} & -x & -y & 0 & z & z^2 \\
    \mathbf{x}^2-wy & -z & \mathbf{w} & 0 & -y & 0 & 0 \\
    \mathbf{xy}-z^2 & 0 & 0 & \mathbf{w} & \mathbf{x} & -y & yz \\
    \mathbf{y}^2-wz & 0 & 0 & -z & -w & \mathbf{x} & \mathbf{w}^2 \\ \hline
    & 0 &  y & -x & \mathbf{w} & -z & 1 \\
    & -y^2+wz & z^2 & -wy  & yz & -w^2 & \mathbf{x}\\
  \end{array}$
  \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Just to complete the list: `\label` is useless without a `\caption`.

Comment: @egreg `\pageref` is still working.