# Problem for bold symbol in math mode with iota

Tags: equations, bold

I am using \mathbf{} for include bold symbols in my equation. It works fine with all symbols with the exception of \iota. I tried to use equation environment and to exclude subindex. The following is my writing:

```
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{Y}=\rho \mathbf{WY}+\alpha \mathbf{\iota}_{N}+\mathbf{X\beta}+\mathbf{WX\theta}+\mathbf{u},\label{eqgeneral1}\\ 
    \mathbf{u}=\lambda\mathbf{Wu}+\mathbf{\varepsilon}  \label{eqgeneral2}
\end{align}
```

I obtain this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

¿How can I solve this?

Comment: It's not just iota though? It's all of the Greek letters right, and there's a very good reason for that. `\mathbf{}` and the standard LaTeX font applies to Roman letters only, not Greek letters, not symbols like + - =, nothing like that. Try: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols

Comment: You can use `\bm` or `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: For new documents, I would recommend loading `unicode-math` instead of legacy font packages. Any Unicode math font is going to come with bold math symbols. You can use them with `\symbf{\iota}` or `\mathbf{\iota}`. It’s also possible to do more complex things, such as using a different font for your Greek alphabet.

Comment: If you’re forced to use pdflatex, you might try the `isomath` package, which supports a large number of Greek math alphabets. You can also use a LGR-encoded legacy Greek font with `mathastext`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user Au101. I used `\boldsymbol` and it works for me:

```
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{Y}=\rho \mathbf{WY}+\alpha \boldsymbol{\iota}_{N}+\mathbf{X\beta}+\mathbf{WX\theta}+\mathbf{u},\label{eqgeneral1}\\ 
    \mathbf{u}=\lambda\mathbf{Wu}+\mathbf{\varepsilon}  \label{eqgeneral2}
\end{align}
```