# How to use \boldsymbol with greek symbols with Tex Gyre Pagella?

Tags: fonts, xetex, tex-gyre-math, boldsymbol

I usually use something like `\boldsymbol\sigma` to obtain bold greek letters, which only requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

This doesn't seem to work when using XeLatex and Tex Gyre Pagella, as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{parskip}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}
$\sigma\boldsymbol{\sigma}$
\end{document}
```

This gives two identical sigma symbols, while removing the block changing the font makes `boldsymbol` work as intended again.

Is there a way to use bold greek symbols with this font?

Comment: Maybe with `\bm`?

Comment: @Bernard ah, that seems to work. It means to use `\pbm` instead of `\boldsymbol` though. Can I just safely use `\renewcommand{\boldsymbol}{\pmb}` for backward compatibility of documents that used the `boldsymbol` syntax?

Comment: But, as far as I know, `\pmb` creates  bitmaps. Why not use `\mathbf`?

Comment: @Bernard is `mathbf` supposed to work on greek symbols? I doesn't work for me (it produces nothing). Using `\bm\sigma` also produces weird output (a bold $0$ instead of the sigma)

Comment: [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/30481) also contains a lot of info on how to make bold symbols, but some of the solutions there don't work when I use this Gyre Pagella font, while others do, and I'm not sure which solution is the preferred one in this case

Comment: You should be using Asana Math for the symbol - not TeX Gyre Pagella. At least, that's what your code seems to want to do.

Comment: @cfr does that make a difference? It's not working whether I include the `Asana Math` line or not

Comment: If it is suppose to be a symbol, it is supposed to come from the maths font and should be `\symbf{\sigma}`. If it is intended to be text, it should use `\mathbf`, but `\sigma` isn't a text-thing, so not what you want here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want, I think, `\symbf`. However, I can't get this to work correctly with Asana Math, even when I load it by filename as XeLaTeX wants.

Here's what it looks like with Latin Modern Math for comparison purposes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{parskip}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0]
% \setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}% ???
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}% default is equivalent
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  & \verb|\math**| & \verb|\sym**| & \verb|\text**|\\
  $xxx$&$\mathup{xxx}$&$\symup{xxx}$&\textup{xxx}\\
  &$\mathit{xxx}$&$\symit{xxx}$&\textit{xxx}\\
  &$\mathbf{xxx}$&$\symbf{xxx}$&\textbf{xxx}\\
  & --&$\symbfit{xxx}$&\textbf{\itshape xxx}\\
  $\sigma$&$\mathup{σ}$&$\symup{σ}$&\textup{σ}\\
  &$\mathit{σ}$&$\symit{σ}$&\textit{σ}\\
  &$\mathbf{σ}$&$\symbf{σ}$&\textbf{σ}\\
  & -- &$\symbfit{σ}$&\textbf{\itshape σ}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: cf. text vs. maths]

If I comment the Latin Modern call and uncomment Asana's, I no longer get a distinction between text and maths --- it all looks like TGP, though the console output doesn't complain.

Comment: For me it works with Asana Math (and Tex Gyre Pagella Math) as well.

Comment: @RalfStubner Interesting. As I say, it doesn't for me at all.