# Why using itemize cannot bold in third line with \(H_{1,1}\)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold

I am trying to bold the word in my third line. as shown in figure below:

[image]

My full MWE is as below:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\blacksquare$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\square$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textendash}
\begin{itemize}
   \item  \textbf{First Line}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item  \textbf{Second Line}
        \begin{itemize}
             \item \textbf{\(H_{1,1}\):} No bold starting here Third Line
                %  \item {\textbf{\(H_{1,2}\):}} There 

\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I had tried:

```
 \item \textbf{\(H_{1,1}\):} No bold starting here Third Line
```

and

```
\item {\textbf{\(H_{1,2}\):}} There
```

Comment: [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/134144)  might be interesting.

Comment: I have edited the tags, especially to remove `biblatex` since this tag is not related to the question. I have added `symbols` and `math-mode` instead.

Comment: Thanks for having provided a MWE. A bit more experimentation shows you can make the example even smaller.

Comment: Actual *minimal* WE: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\(H_{1,2}\):}
\end{document}` since the problem is not related to `itemize`. (As also stated by Arnaud).

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. I was thinking `\(H_{1,2}\` is not math symbols. I had tried `\usepackage{amsbsy}` and `$\boldsymbol{\(H_{1,1}\)}$`, not correct

Comment: @aan: `\(` starts and `\)` ends inline math mode See also: [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/134144)

Comment: `$\boldsymbol{\(H_{1,1}\)}$`  can not work. The `$` signs are not needed and `\boldsymbol` should be used inside of `\(` and `\)`. Instead `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\(\boldsymbol{H_{1,2}}\)\textbf{:}
\end{document}` would be the way to go.

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. Brillant. you can write an answer, i will need to edit my question that is not related to \itemize

Comment: @aan: I actually think, your question is quite similar to the one I linked [in my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521777/why-using-itemize-cannot-bold-in-third-line-with-h-1-1#comment1319447_521777). Would you agree closing yours as a duplicate instead?

Comment: @leandriis. Yes, you can mark as duplicated. Thanks for pointing out, i much appreciate. Even I had read the link, still hard to figure out.

Comment: @leandriis, yes, it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To make the math expression bold, you need to use `\mathbf{}` inside the math expression (i.e. `\( \mathbf{...} \)` rather than `\textbf{ \(...\) }`).

Or else, a bad way out is to use "poor man's bold" or `\pmb{}` in place of `\textbf{}`  which gives you a *fake* bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\blacksquare$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\square$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textendash}
\begin{itemize}
   \item  \textbf{First Line}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item  \textbf{Second Line}
        \begin{itemize}
             \item \textbf{\(H_{1,1}\):} No bold starting here Third Line
             \item \( \mathbf{H_{1,1}} \): Math bold font in fourth Line
             \item \pmb{\(H_{1,1}\):} Poor man's bold in fifth Line
                %  \item {\textbf{\(H_{1,2}\):}} There 

\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

to get something of this sort:

[image]

To get a bold colon (**:**) on the fourth line, place the colon inside`\ mathbf{}`, i.e. use `\( \mathbf{H_{1,1}:} \)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not related to being a third item, but to trying having math being bold with \textbf.

Comment: @Arnuad, thanks. i was thinking `\(H_{1,2}` is not a math symbol.

Comment: \\( ... \\) is equivalent to $ ... $
(in fact there is a subtle difference, don't ask me though)

Comment: @CampanIgnis : what new question are you referring to?

Comment: @Arnoud that was an automatic comment made by the system (note the _From Review_ link) that was generated because the reviewer (CampanIgnis) clicked the 'in my opinion this is a different question posted as an answer' option. He may have thought that you wanted to ask a new question, i.e., "how can I use `\textbf` to write bold math?" or something similar. That was probably a review mistake, in my opinion this is an (accurate) answer to the question, although a bit short.

Comment: @Arnaud. See Marijn comment. Marion is correct.