# Normal Text font under math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, text-manipulation

I want to write symbols in the math mode in the normal font as the text. A picture for the same is attached. The code for the math mode is as follows.

'''$14,\mu m {\times} 95 , {\mu} m$'''

I want the math mode in between the line to follow the same font as the text outside math mode.

[image]

Comment: Off topic: I'd recommend `siunitx`-package for writing numbers with units, e.g. `$\SI{14}{\micro\metre}\times\SI{95}{\micro\metre}$`. It provides correct spacing and prints units upright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mixture of mathmode and text is always a bit tricky. Since you are not talking about maths specifically, but numbers with units I would suggest you try the `siunitx` package with the `detect-all=true` option.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[detect-all=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Some text \SI{14}{\micro\meter} $\bm{\times}$ \SI{95}{\micro\metre}.}
    \textbf{Some text \SI{14}{$\upmu$\meter} $\bm{\times}$ \SI{95}{$\upmu$\metre}.}
\end{document}
```

Note how I used the `upgreek` package to demonstrate two methods of implementing the µ in µm. Which one you like better is of course up to you. Just don't mix them.

Most mathematical symbols do not come in a bold version, but there a few packages that help with that. I used `\bm` here, but also have look at this overview: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99286/118712

Comment: Thanks a lot this is helpful.