# Bold version of `mathscr`

Tags: math-mode, bold, boldmath

I use the package `mathrsfs` to get a separate `\mathscr`. While I like the way it looks, it does not come with a bold version. More specifically, the usual `\mathcal` is compatible with `\boldsymbol` and `\boldmath` (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols)), whereas `\mathscr` is not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[
    \mathcal{S}, \mathscr{S}.
\]
\[
    \boldsymbol{\mathcal{S}}, \boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: not bold v. bold]

Is there an alternative package that provides similar looking letters to `mathrsfs`, but which does come with a bold version?

Comment: You can also give a look at the `mathalpha` package. Its documentation contains some lists of calligraphic fonts including some which come with a bold variant.

Comment: @campa that is a very useful list! Many thanks. That deserves to be an answer (or at least a comment) on the other question, in my opinion :)