# Making bold math symbols more bold

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, bold

I am writing some equations where I need to distinguish between bold and non-bold quantities. However, for some symbols there is barely any difference when I just use `\mathbf` or `\boldsymbol`. Is there a way to 'increase the boldness' of math symbols?

Comment: If you can be more specific about which symbols you find aren't bold enough, probably someone can help.  A small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` demonstrating the problem, would be even better.

Comment: In particular, do please tell us *which* math font you employ.

Comment: There is also this extensive thread on the subject: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/118712

Comment: It is hard to distinguish between bold $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I found that the problem is not that the bold is not bold enough, rather that it is bold when it is not supposed to. The problem disappears if I remove the package "mathptmx".

Comment: mathptmx is a very old package with very limited font support and no support for bold math symbols at all. There is no reason to use it now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In comments it is stated that you are using `mathptmx` this is an old package targetting the fonts available in early PostScript laser printers. It has no support for bold math.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

 $\alpha$ \boldmath  $\alpha$
\end{document}
```

produces the warning

```
Package mathptmx Warning: There are no bold math fonts on input line 7.
```

If you want a Times-like math font that has support for bold symbols use for example `newtxmath` or `stix2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

 $\alpha$ \boldmath  $\alpha$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have removed the package. It was part of a template for writing articles in the Journal of Chemical Physics. It looks much better now.

Comment: @Physics101 OK but be careful of changing font choices on journal submissions it can invalidate the submission if it messes up the journal production.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The professor that I am working with will read it and help with the formalities before submission. I will ask him for a better template now.

Comment: @Physics101 the professor probably won't be much help; the journal might be.  Most professors rely on their postdocs or even students to fiddle with that sort of detail

Comment: Also, with these packages, you might consider using upright greek letters `\upalpha` etc. in the bold cases (as `\boldsymbol{\upalpha}`) for extra distinction.

Answer (score 4):

In `unicode-math`, you can declare a bold math version and use `\boldsymbol`.  XITS Math comes with one, and `\setmathfont{XITS Math}` will load it automatically for `\boldsymbol`, `\boldmath` and `\mathversion{bold}`.  You could also embolden a math font with `FakeBold`, as in:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[
   version = bold,
   FakeBold = 1.2 ]
```

The one disadvantage of this is that, as of 2021, you cannot combine `version=` and `range=`.

In legacy 8-bit TeX, you normally want to load a newer font package that comes in a bold version.  You can also declare a bold version for any math alphabet with e.g. `\SetMathAlphabet`, or a bold version of any math symbol font with `\SetSymbolFont` (and then optionally use the symbol font as a math alphabet as well, with `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`). See [The LaTeX Font Selection Guide](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf#section.3) for the full details.