# How can I change all the math symbols to bold math symbols?

Tags: boldmath

I have wrote a text of math with several pages. How can I change **all** the math symbols to bold math symbols?

I know from the page [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols) that I can use `\boldsymbols` or `\mathbf` after every dollor. But is there any global way to achieve that? (for example are there a code before \begin{document} like "\renewcommand...")

Comment: `\boldmath` in the preamble would take care of most (but not all) symbols.

Comment: Off-topic: how you will distinguish vector from scalar variables? I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @campa Yes. It works for all my symbols. Thank you very much. Do you  know How  I can find the symbols that works with this command?

Comment: it depends which fonts you are using, if there is no bold font you'll get the normal weight one, eg \mathbb fonts are typically not available in  bold, and if you choose a non standard math font set some have no bold at all.

Comment: @Zarko  I think we can use \unboldmath for scalar variables.

Comment: I don't know what is  background of your intention, that you oppose usual, vell establish and supported, typographically deliberate selected  way of writing math. However, I would do this., but you are free to do what you like :-)