# On controlling the linewidth of the wire and border of a voltage source and the font size of its polarity +-

Tags: circuitikz

Let us assume that we plan to draw a voltage source using the code as below:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{20}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw [ line width=0.1pt,gray] (-1,0) grid (1,3);
    \draw [font=\myfont,line width=2pt](0,0)
    to[V, v=$V$, invert] (0,3);        
      \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]
I have the following questions:

1. How to make the + and - thicker? obviously as I tried changing the fontsize in \draw does not work.
2. Why the linewidth of the wire is thinner than that of the circle? How to make both 1 pt line width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to your questions:

1. If [you look at the manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.3.3), the default style for sources is to have the symbol's element drawn with a line thickness which is twice the default thickness for the path element. This is because by default `sources/thickness` is `none`, which makes them [defaulting to the legacy](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#paragraph.3.1.4.2) `bipoles/thickness` which is `2`.

   I also do not like it (my style, which is distributed with the package, has `sources/thickness=1`. You can learn more about styles in https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.3.3)
2. The `+` and `-` are not drawn, they are symbols. You can look [at the example in the manual on how to change them](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#paragraph.4.5.8.3).

I suppose that what you want is this (I am using `bm` for the boldmath, but [there are several options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols)).

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{20}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
% manual 1.3.4 page 40 (3.3.3 line thickness)
\ctikzset{sources/thickness=1}
% manual 1.3.4 page 69 (examples of sources customization)
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={$\bm{+}$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={$\bm{-}$}}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw [ line width=0.1pt,gray] (-1,0) grid (1,3);
    \draw [font=\myfont,line width=2pt](0,0)
    to[V, v=$V$, invert] (0,3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rmano can you make the +- more thick?

Comment: You can either find a font with ultra bold symbols or use @john-kormylo trick...

Answer (score 2):

This helps a little.  You can also make the letters larger, but the height and width increase more obviously than the thickness.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{bm}

\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={$\bm{+}$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={$\bm{-}$}}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{20}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw [ line width=0.1pt,gray] (-1,0) grid (1,3);
    \draw [font=\myfont,line width=2pt](0,0)
    to[V, v=$V$, invert] (0,3);        
      \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

---

This uses `\myfont`.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newcommand{\myfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{20}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}

\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={\myfont $+$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={\myfont $-$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw [ line width=0.1pt,gray] (-1,0) grid (1,3);
    \draw [line width=2pt](0,0)
    to[V, v=$V$, invert] (0,3);        
      \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

---

This allows you to draw the plus and minus using TikZ.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newsavebox{\bplus}
\savebox{\bplus}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (0,\ht\strutbox)
    (-0.5\ht\strutbox, 0.5\ht\strutbox) -- (0.5\ht\strutbox, 0.5\ht\strutbox);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newsavebox{\bminus}
\savebox{\bminus}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
  \draw[line width=1pt] (-0.5\ht\strutbox, 0.5\ht\strutbox) -- (0.5\ht\strutbox, 0.5\ht\strutbox);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner plus={\usebox\bplus}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={\usebox\bminus}}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw [ line width=0.1pt,gray] (-1,0) grid (1,3);
    \draw [line width=2pt](0,0)
    to[V, v=$V$, invert] (0,3);        
      \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks John I appreciate the time you spent but that is not the answer

Comment: Thanks John your 3rd answer shows thicker + and -. Do you know how to change the linewidth of the circle and wire independently?

Comment: @Aria, this is explained in my answer. Read answer 1 there, `\ctikzset{sources/thickness=1}` sets the relative thickness of the circle.

Comment: Yes Rmano so the combination of Rmano+John is the answer