# Impossible to put some math in pdfpages' addtotoc

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, pdfpages

The following MCE shows that `pdfpages`' `addtotoc` option works well, even with basic math but, if the commented line is uncommented, shows that it doesn't work with less basic math (here `\mathbf`, though this command works well in usual ToC), the compilation failing with the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.11   }]{example-image.pdf}
```

Adding `\protect` before `\mathbf{R}^{n}` doesn't help.

Do you understand what is going on and how to get around it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={
    1,section,1,{No math},ex-1
    , 1,section,1,{Basic math: $R^{n}$},ex-2
    % , 1,section,1,{Not so basic math: $\mathbf{R}^{n}$},ex-3
  }]{example-image.pdf}
\section{$\mathbf{R}^{n}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\protect\mathbf`?

Comment: Yes: same error.

Comment: You could put the text into a marxo or savebox in the premamble.  \protect will prevent it from being expanded too soon.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Not very handy if there are numerous such entries in the ToC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdfpages uses `\edef` a bit to often ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\define@key{pdfpages}{addtotoc}{\protected@edef\AM@toclist{#1,}}%replace \edef
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents  
\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={
    %1,section,1,{No math},ex-1
    %, 1,section,1,{Basic math: $R^{n}$},ex-2
     1,section,1,{Not so basic math: $\mathbf{R}^{n}$},ex-3
  }]{example-image.pdf}
\section{$\mathbf{R}^{n}$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one possibility.

With `unicode-math` you can use `\symbf{<characters>}` which works for both Greek and Latin letters.

Compile with xelatex or lualatex.

[bold math symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38631/161015)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}% added <<<<<<<<
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular.otf}% added <<<<<<<<

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \includepdf[
    pages=-,
    addtotoc={
        1,section,1,{No math},ex-1
        , 1,section,1,{Basic math: $R^{n}$},ex-2
         , 1,section,1,{Not so basic math: $\symbf{R}^{n}$},ex-3 %changed <<<<<
    }]{example-image.pdf}
    \section{$\mathbf{R}^{n}$}
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % added <<<<
\usepackage{unicode-math}% added <<<<

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \includepdf[
    pages=-,
    addtotoc={
        1,section,1,{No math},ex-1
        , 1,section,1,{Basic math: $R^{n}$},ex-2
         , 1,section,1,{Not so basic math:  $\mathbf{R}^{n}$},ex-3
    }]{example-image.pdf}
    \section{$\mathbf{R}^{n}$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution. As shown by the following MCE, it is enough (and maybe necessary for commands with arguments: see `\textit`) to prevent the expansion of the culprit commands with `\noexpand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={
    1,section,1,{No math},ex-1
    , 1,section,1,{Basic math: $R^{n}$},ex-2
    , 1,section,1,{Not so basic math: {$\noexpand\mathbf{R}^{n}$}},ex-3
    , 1,section,1,{Not so basic command: \noexpand\textit{Foo}},ex-4
  }]{example-image.pdf}
\section{$\mathbf{R}^{n}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `{\unexpanded{Not so basic math: $\mathbf{R}^{n}$}}` should work too. but one should check what pdfpages is doing ...