# Bad spacing of math letters within italic text

Tags: fonts, spacing, italic, italic-correction

I use the standard AMS theorem style, which means that my theorems are set in italic. In combination with math variables, this sometimes gives horrible spacing: The input `If $U$ or $V$ \dots` yields

[image]

I see two spacing problems here: The space between "If" and "U" is too small, and the space between "U" and "or" is too large. Thus, the output would look a lot better if the "U" would be moved a bit to the right. One non-solution is to remove the dollar signs: `If U or V \dots` yields

[image]

Here the spacing is a lot better, but now the problem is that a different font (namely italic) is used for "U" and "V", which is similar but not quite the same. Another non-solution is to use italic correction `\/` after "If": This only corrects the first space (and it is not nice if one has to remember typing `\/` all the time).

My present "solution" is to apply manual corrections where I find it appropriate, which of course is a real nuisance. Does anyone have a better solution? Do XeTeX or LuaTeX offer something?

(I think I do understand what causes the problem. The idea is to show the bounding boxes of the relevant characters in both examples:

[image]       
[image]

What you see is that the spacing of the bounding boxes is good in both cases. But the italic letters tend to stick out of their boxes to the right, and with "U" (in the right picture) and "o" you see that they have some white space in the left of the box. The math "U" (in the left picture), however, does not have this white space in the left, and it doesn't stick out to the right. As a result, the math "U" sits too far to the left.)

EDIT:

Khaled is quite right, the space between the math "U" and "or" is so large since the math "U" includes an italic correction. This is explicitly described in the infamous Appendix G of the TeXbook, rule 17. So the math "U" doesn't stick out of its box since the box includes the italic correction, and this is quite alright if the math in embedded in roman text. I just have no idea how to get rid of the italic correction if the math is already in some italic text!

Comment: I don't no much TeX to have an answer, but you need to prevent italic correction inside the second formula after the U, the italic correction is the extra white space you see after the U.

Comment: nobody has mentioned that if a line in an italic paragraph begins with a word like "Very", that line will look indented relative to the lines above and below.  so it's not only math that's a problem ...  the solution will need to know the *shapes* of the characters, not just the metrics.

Comment: @barbara: Thanks for your comment. I've mentioned (actually rather _complained about_) this in [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10095/can-i-get-full-justification-for-italic-text). The solution is using microtype with an improved protrusion table. I've mailed this improved table to Robert Schlicht, but I don't know if it's incorporated into microtype already.

Comment: LuaTeX seems to have some `mmathitalicsmode` thing https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642201/is-there-a-way-to-add-italic-correction-at-the-end-of-inline-math?noredirect=1&lq=1. I didn't try it myself however.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, I produced an absolutely crazy "solution" myself. This is mostly to make clearer what the problems are; I wouldn't suggest using the (very long) code below. This "solution" only provides italic correction for single letters `A` to `Z` and `a` to `z`, and it works by making `$` active. (I could also have used `\(` and `\)`, but I don't like those.) Moreover, everything is adjusted "by hand" for 10pt CM fonts, so it won't work for other fonts (but should approximately work for other font sizes). Here's the output:

[image]

In the 1st line you see the result of `If $U$ or $V$ ...` without any correction; in the 2nd line my correction is applied, and in the 3rd line the `$`s are omitted, i.e., the usual italic font is used. I'm not claiming that the 2nd line is good on all counts, e.g. the space between "f" and "from" is rather small. What I wanted to achieve is that the spacing is just as with the "normal" italic font, that is, in the second and third lines the spacing is (almost) the same. (The 2nd line is slightly longer since the math letters are wider.)

Note in particular that the spacing before punctuation in the 2nd line is different from the 1st line. (I'm not sure which version is the better one.) Clearly, the positioning of "U", "V" and "Y" in the 1st line is not good (I would say horrible); in the 2nd line it's a lot better.

Of course one could change all these numbers in my code to try and further improve the spacing. But I only wanted to point out something else: If you look at the numbers, then you see that it would be very hard indeed to have this correction "automatically" and without changing the font metrics.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\mydollar=$
\catcode`\$=\active
\def\my@testtoken{\my@testtoken}
\def$#1${\ifx\my@testtoken#1\my@testtoken
           \mydollar\mydollar
         \else
           \test@single@character#1\my@testtoken
         \fi
        }
\def\test@single@character#1#2\my@testtoken{%
         \def\math@format##1{\mydollar##1\mydollar}%
         \ifx\mytesttoken#2\mytesttoken
           \ifcat#1a%
             \ifdim\fontdimen\@ne\font>\z@
               \def\math@format##1{\mydollar\xdef\currentfont{\the\textfont1}\mydollar
                                   {\corrected{##1}}%\currentfont##1}%
                                  }%
             \fi
           \fi
         \fi
         \math@format{#1#2}%
        }
\def\corrected#1{\csname @correct@#1\endcsname}
\def\correct#1#2,#3,{\expandafter\def\csname @correct@#1\endcsname{\mydollar\mskip#2mu#1\mskip-#3mu\mydollar}}
\makeatother

\correct A0.15,0,    %1st number is the correction before the letter,
\correct B0.3,1.5,   %2nd number is (minus) the correction after it.
\correct C1.75,2.2,
\correct D0.25,1.4,
\correct E0.3,1.7,
\correct F0.3,1.95,
\correct G1.8,1.15,
\correct H0.25,2.6,
\correct I0.3,2.6,
\correct J0.1,2.2,
\correct K0.3,2.4,
\correct L0.25,0.6,
\correct M0.3,2.6,
\correct N0.3,2.6,
\correct O1.75,1.3,
\correct P0.2,1.5,
\correct Q1.75,1.3,
\correct R0.2,0.2,
\correct S0.4,1.8,
\correct T2.7,1.9,
\correct U2.4,2.6,
\correct V2.4,2.95,
\correct W2.4,2.9,
\correct X0.4,2.5,
\correct Y2.6,3.1,
\correct Z0.4,2.2,
\correct a1.2,1,
\correct b1.2,0.3,
\correct c1.2,0.2,
\correct d1.2,0.8,
\correct e1.2,0.85,
\correct f-1.5,3.5,
\correct g0.7,1.2,
\correct h0.4,1,
\correct i1,1.4,
\correct j-0.5,2.2,
\correct k0.4,1.5,
\correct l0.9,1.8,
\correct m1,0.95,
\correct n1,0.95,
\correct o1.2,0.3,
\correct p1,0.3,
\correct q1.2,1.2,
\correct r1,2,
\correct s0.5,1,
\correct t1,1.25,
\correct u1,0.95,
\correct v1,1.55,
\correct w1,1.5,
\correct x0.4,1.75,
\correct y1,1.2,
\correct z0.4,1.75,

\newcommand\test[1]{%
    {\let$\mydollar #1} \par
    #1 \par
    \let$\relax #1
    }

\begin{document}
\it
\test{If $U$ or $V$ and $X$, and $f$ from $j$.  Let $T$ be $S$ if $Y$.}
\end{document}
```

--- edit ---

Here's a version of the above correction table for use with newtxtext and newtxmath.

```
\correct A-1.3,-0.2,
\correct B-0.6,0.3,
\correct C0.2,0.9,
\correct D-0.6,0.4,
\correct E-0.55,1.4,
\correct F-2.6,1.1,
\correct G0.0,0.5,
\correct H-0.4,1.0,
\correct I-0.75,1.3,
\correct J-1.0,1.15,
\correct K-0.25,1.3,
\correct L-0.9,0.95,
\correct M-1.0,1.35,
\correct N-2.55,1.55,
\correct O0.25,0.5,
\correct P-0.65,0.45,
\correct Q0.2,0.5,
\correct R-0.8,0.2,
\correct S-0.4,0.6,
\correct T0.7,1.85,
\correct U0.5,1.05,
\correct V0.5,1.65,
\correct W0.5,1.5,
\correct X-1.0,1.45,
\correct Y1.0,1.95,
\correct Z-1.0,1.45,
\correct a-0.3,0.25,
\correct b-0.5,-0.3,
\correct c-0.3,0.35,
\correct d-0.5,0.9,
\correct e-0.25,0.35,
\correct f-3.15,3.15,
\correct g-0.05,0.55,
\correct h-0.6,0.35,
\correct i0.35,0.7,
\correct j-2.0,1.3,
\correct k-0.65,1.3,
\correct l-0.1,1.1,
\correct m-0.2,0.15,
\correct n-0.2,0.0,
\correct o-0.25,0.05,
\correct p-0.75,0.0,
\correct q-0.2,0.4,
\correct r0.2,1.3,
\correct s-0.55,0.45,
\correct t0.15,1.2,
\correct u0.1,0.25,
\correct v-0.1,0.75,
\correct w-0.25,0.6,
\correct x-0.95,0.85,
\correct y-1.0,0.7,
\correct z-0.5,0.55,
```

Comment: Nice job.  Maybe you should submit this patch to mathtools?

Comment: @Matthew: Glad that you like it, but as I wrote above: It's more a case study since it is tested only with 10pt CM, and works only for single latin letters. I'd need someone professional to make a good patch out of it, I think.

Comment: @EricPeterson - Thanks for providing the addendum for the`txfonts` package. The `txfonts` package is actually considered to be somewhat obsolete, and a successor package -- indeed, a pair of packages: `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` -- has been available for several years now. Might you be interested in providing a similar patch that's applicable to the newtxmath` package? (You could probably use your work for the `txfonts` package as a good starting point.)

Comment: I didn't realize that—Cambridge University Press is still advocating it as their standard font choice, so I thought it was still in rotation. In fact, something seems to be wrong with what I've posted above; I'll use the newer package and fix the tables both.

Comment: I know this is quite an old subject, but in case you are interested I somehow automated your code here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513441/why-are-inline-math-symbols-shifted-left-when-used-inside-italic-text

Answer (score 21):

This is partially fixed in the `mathtools` package (see section 4.1 of the package documentation).

Here is an example. Note that math must be typed using `\(` and `\)`:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}  
\begin{document}  
Bad:  
\mathtoolsset{mathic=false}   
\textit{If \(U\) or \(V\) \dots.}  
\par Good:  
\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}  
\textit{If \(U\) or \(V\) \dots.}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, no, this only solves half of my problem: It automatically puts the italic correction after "If" that I mentioned in my question (so it saves me typing `\/` all the time), but it does not correct the space between "U" and "or". Moreover, I don't like using `\(` and `\)`. Still, this answer is not bad: The output does look better with `mathic=true`.

Comment: I see, it doesn't fully do what it advertises.... And perhaps some guru can explain why mathtools needs the `\( \)' delimiters to work.

Comment: I'm not a guru, but mathtools just redefines '\\(' so that it can do the italic correction, but it doesn't alter '$'

Comment: I still find the answer interesting, but after a bit more of testing I don't like the `mathic=true` option that much any more. In the cases "If $T$" and "If $U$" you definitely want italic correction, but it is not nice at all in the cases "If $A$" and "If $f$", always assuming the "If" to be italic.

Comment: So there's a need for a better package for italic correction in maths than mathtools.

Comment: @Konrad: Oh yes, italics are in dire need of correction ... I think it'll be very hard to write a package that gives a satisfactory solution. The problems are just builtin in the fonts, so the solution probably has to be more global. See also my crazy attempt that I'm going to add as an answer now.

Comment: Has Knuth given any recommendations about how to deal with this problem? I can't find anything explicitly about it in the _TeXbook_. Interestingly, on page 340 is, effectively, `{\sl ... of $math$ is ...}`. (It does look odd in typeset form on page 341.)

Comment: @MSC-- as far as i know, knuth is aware of the problem but it's a much bigger one than he wanted to tackle, and it really didn't affect "the art of computer programming" which, of course, is the reason tex exists at all.  he's also quite willing to make small manual adjustments for things that don't happen too often.  for example, i'm willing to bet that he always puts `\/` after an "f" that comes just before math in an italic environment (unless, of course, the "f" happens to fall at the end of a line, in which case i'm not sure).

Comment: @barbarabeeton there is a way, see my answer.

Answer (score 17):

*Update: this [previous answer to another, related, question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71065) already mentioned the `\noic` macro which is discussed here.*

Here is how to suppress the italic correction when exiting math after a letter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vscale=0.82]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\def\noic{\sb{}\kern-\scriptspace }
\def\mathfont{\usefont{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}}

\mathsurround0pt % is default anyhow

\newbox\letterbox
\newcount\letter
%\the\scriptspace

\begin{verbatim}
\def\noic{\sb{}\kern-\scriptspace }
    $<letter>\noic$ gives the same as \usefont{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}<letter> 
©jfbu, 2013. 
          <letter>     <letter>\/    $<letter>$  $<letter>_{}$  $<letter>\noic$ 
\end{verbatim}

\letter`a
\noindent\loop
\makebox[.05\linewidth]{$\char\letter$}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{\mathfont\char\letter}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{\mathfont\char\letter\/}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{$\char\letter$}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{$\char\letter_{}$}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{$\char\letter\noic$}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}\\
\ifnum\letter<`z
\advance\letter by 1 
\repeat

%\clearpage

\letter`A

\noindent\loop
\makebox[.05\linewidth]{$\char\letter$}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{\mathfont\char\letter}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{\mathfont\char\letter\/}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{$\char\letter$}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{$\char\letter_{}$}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}%
\setbox\letterbox=\hbox{$\char\letter\noic$}%
\makebox[.18\linewidth][r]{\the\wd\letterbox}\\
\ifnum\letter<`Z
\advance\letter by 1 
\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image: table of all OML letters with and without italic corrections]

On popular request,

```
\clearpage
\newgeometry{hscale=0.9}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\def\original{If $U$ or $V$ and $X$, and $f$ from $j$.  Let $T$ be $S$ if $Y$.}

\def\improved{If\/ $U\noic$ or\/ $V\noic$ and\/ $X\noic$, and\/ $f$ from\/ $j\noic$. Let\/ $T\noic$ be\/ $S\noic$ if\/ $Y\noic$.}

\normalfont\itshape


\small
\original

\improved

\medskip

\normalsize
\original

\improved

\medskip

\large
\original

\improved

\medskip

\huge
\original

\improved

\medskip

\bigskip

\bfseries\boldmath


\small
\original

\improved

\medskip

\normalsize
\original

\improved

\medskip

\large
\original

\improved

\medskip

\huge
\original

\improved
```

[image: examples]

Comment: you've produced a table of the values of the italic correction for `cmmi10`, but you haven't shown how to use the values in a simple example.  i'd like to see a minimal example using the sentence shown in the accepted answer, as `\textit{...}`, using only the defined macro in the recommended manner.  oh, please do it also in several sizes: normal size, `\small` and `\large`, without changing the macro definition.

Comment: @barbarabeeton what do you mean by 'how to use the values'? the values are not used, they were just displayed to see the effect of the `\noic` macro I defined.

Comment: i was mistaken about how to use `\noic`.  the use example clarifies that very nicely.  thanks.  however, the input is really too complicated for most people (and rather error prone for your average typist); i think that using `mathtools` and `\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}` us probably the best compromise, even though it requires using `\(...\)` rather than `$...$`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton perhaps the developpers of `mathtools` will find a way to modify `\)` and add the `\noic` macro if necessary. But this will be more difficult than the modification of `\(` (this modification just adds the italic correction in the appropriate manner, which requires testing the `\fontdimen1` parameter of the font; for `\)` it seems what one would have to know if the formula ended with a letter: I have not at all tested what `\noic` does if the formula ends otherwise). Besides, there is `no` `\everyendofmath` hook in `TeX` (so `$` is difficult).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the "post math correction" is quite good in many (most?) cases! But it doesn't always work since the italic correction in math mode is designed for _subscript positioning_ only: compare, e.g., `$F\noic$ f` with `$H\noic$ f`. Also, the "pre math correction" doesn't quite work; see [my 3rd comment to Konrad's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/91373#comment5801_3496). (I've actually [learned a few months ago that one can use `_{}\kern-\scriptspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71065) to get rid of the italic correction, but I never tried it here!)

Comment: @barbara beeton: You might be interested in my above comment.

Comment: @HendrikVogt yes you are right on it not being a foolproof fix for "post math" and I am sorry for the duplicate  `_{}\kern-\scriptspace`! I did not know about  [this other answer of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71065) ...

Comment: @jfbu: No need to be sorry! Your answer still gives a huge improvement over the default spacing, and I already gave it a +1. Thanks again!