# Space between emphasized word and parenthesis

Tags: emphasis, italic-correction, rendering

When I have the following text

```
(\emph{WSJ})
```

the J will touch the parenthesis in an ugly way (my opinion). Is LaTeX supposed to keep some space there? How can I get some more space there in a a nice way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't really see the `J` *touching* the parenthesis, but I do agree that the output is ugly. I find it ugly since the space between `(` and `W` is much larger than the space between `J` and `)`; in fact, in my opinion this first space is much too large. The problem is that there is an italic correction after the `J`, so that there is at least a little space between `J` and `)`, but there is no sort of correction *before* the `W`. Look at the bounding box of the italic letter `W` to see the problem:

[image]

It is the white space in the left of the bounding box that makes `WSJ` look not centered in the parentheses. I'm afraid there is no clean solution for this, so you have to use manual spacing corrections, as Harald proposed. I find that `(\!\emph{WSJ})` yields much better output:

[image]

(See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3490/1235) question of mine that deals with the same problem in the definition of the italic fonts.)

Comment: (Commentary.) It's unfortunate (but understandable) that TeX has no left-side italic correction, and it's not clear whether it's appropriate to mirror the right-side italic correction to the left even if you can create a macro which does that. (Although usually it would probably work well.) The whole concept of kerning between different fonts is pretty murky and I don't think anyone's really done much about it—although perhaps Indesign's optical kerning tackles the problem. Your manual negative space is probably the best approach.

Comment: @Will Robertson: I'm not sure, but I always thought it would indeed be appropriate to have some italic correction to the left, and it has bothered me for a long time that it seems that this can't be done. Can you think of an example where this left correction wouldn't be appropriate?

Comment: Oh, I only meant that using the right italic correction on the left might sometimes give poor results. I agree a right-side italic correction would be a useful tool.

Comment: @Will Robertson: OK, now I understand what you mean. Using the right side correction on the left should indeed give very poor results for "f", but might be OK for "W".

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking. And I obviously meant to write "left-side italic correction would be useful", sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it does. Compare with `({\em WSJ})` which adds no italic correction. If the italic correction is not sufficient, you may wish to add a small bit of explicit `\hspace` yourself.

Answer (score 7):

I also think that the italic correction after `J` is appropriate and that the missing negative kerning in front of `W` is responsible for the suboptimal output. If you use pdfTeX (PDF- or DVI-mode) you can cope with this problem (and similar ones) by means of the kerning feature of the [`microtype`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[kerning]{microtype}

\SetExtraKerning[context=pemph]{encoding={OT1}, shape=it}{W={-150,}}
```

Now, you can define a command `\pemph` automatically taking care of the desirable kerning in front of `W` which results in a better centring of `\emph{WSJ}` inside the pair of parentheses:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\pemph}[1]{%
  (\emph{\microtypecontext{kerning=pemph}#1})%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\pemph{WSJ}\\
(\emph{WSJ})

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]

Note that the `microtype` package is designed to work with both pdfTeX and luaTeX. The kerning feature is currently only available for pdfTeX, though.

Comment: Nice idea to use microtype. But your solution doesn't _automatically_ take care of the desirable kerning, does it? You'd need to manually find out a whole lot of `\SetExtraKerning` values, wouldn't you?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Yes, you have to specify the desirable kerning for each character.

Comment: I wonder about 2 things: 1. Why do you have to specify a protrusion of `{-150,}` (with `-` sign) if the "usual" protrusion for `W` in cmr-it is `{100,}`, or `{185,-55}` in the most recent `microtype` version (without `-` sign)? 2. Can't one somehow use those "usual" protrusion values? (I'm not sure if they really fit.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: According to the `microtype` documentation, protrusion and kerning are different concepts. `W={-150,}` as argument of `\SetExtraKerning` specifies additional negative kerning equal to 150/1000 of the character width at the left side of `W`. Obviously, no additional kerning is desirable at the right side of `W` in the current context. If you want to reuse the protrusion value of `W`, try `W={-185,}`. I’d say this is also OK.