# Can I get full justification for italic text?

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment, microtype, italic, protrusion

In the TeXbook, Knuth notes that italics can lead to problems with justification:

> EXERCISE 14.16
>   When an entire paragraph is typeset in italic or slanted type, it sometimes appears to be offset on the page with respect to other paragraphs. Explain how you could use `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` to shift all lines of a paragraph left by 1`pt`.

The following text shows that one can even get *fluttering* margins:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=3.85cm
\begin{document}
\it\noindent
This is a small text. If jam is what you like, two fingers up,
or whatever. Under certain conditions you see that the left and
right margins flutter.
\end{document}
```

The effect is a bit overemphazised by the small `\textwidth`, but the compilation doesn't show any overfull hboxes. In particular the left margin looks awful in my opinion.

Is there any way to overcome this problem in TeX? I'd prefer a LaTeX answer, but in the end I'm open to any TeX version.

I know that this is actually a font problem; and it happens due to the way the CM italic font is designed. (In fact I have already [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/bad-spacing-of-math-letters-within-italic-text) and [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/space-between-emphasized-word-and-parenthesis/4189#4189) a few questions concerning problems with italics.) Is there an italic font where the problem is less prominent or even non-existent?

Comment: and why don't you use package `microtype`?

Comment: @Herbert: OK, at close inspection I see that indeed this helps a bit, thanks. But it doesn't make the problem go away.

Comment: Yes, `microtype` is the way to go in this case. You should IMO put this as an answer, Herbert.

Comment: Hendrik: you probably need to set the lpcode and the efcode of the glyphs.

Comment: @Patrick: At the time of your comment, I had no idea what you're talking about. Now I looked at `mt-cmr.def`: Do you mean the `A = {50,50}` stuff in `\SetProtrusion`? (And can you explain why the values for `cmr-it` are chosen in such a way that you still have heavy flutter?)

Comment: @Hendrik: I only know the low level interface for pdftex, not the package microtype itself. The quoted command `\SetProtrusion` looks like it is exactly what I mean. I have no idea about the values of this font.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*With version 2.5 of the* [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) *package, available on CTAN since 13 March 2013, the simple answer to my question is "use* `microtype`*".*

---

Thanks, Herbert and Joseph, for telling me that this can be done with the `microtype` package. I did know that `microtype` can do margin kerning, but I had always thought that this is only about punctuation. In reality, one can adjust the margin kerning for every single letter.

What I had been wondering: Why is the output in Herbert's and Joseph's answer a bit better, but still far from good? The answer, of course, is that the margin kerning table provided by `microtype` just isn't good enough. So I went ahead and went through all the letters ... The output now looks as follows, and I'm quite happy with it:

[image]

Here's the code, which essentially consists of the adjusted margin kerning table *(that has now been added to the* [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) *package)*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=3.85cm
\usepackage{microtype}
\LoadMicrotypeFile{cmr}
\SetProtrusion
   [ name     = cmr-it   ]
   { }
   {
     A = {100,100},
     B = {83,-40},
     C = {165,-75},
     D = {75, -28},
     E = {80,-55},
     F = {85,-80},
     G = {153,-15},
     H = {73,-60},
     I = {140,-120},
     J = {135,-80},
     K = {70,-30},
     L = {87, 40},
     M = {67,-45},
     N = {75,-55},
     O = {150,-30},
     P = {82,-50},
     Q = {150,-30},
     R = {75, 15},
     S = {90,-65},
     $ = {100,-20},
     T = {220,-85},
     U = {230,-55},
     V = {260,-60},
     W = {185,-55},
     X = {70,-30},
     Y = {250,-60},
     Z = {90,-60},
     a = {150,-10},
     b = {170,   },
     c = {173,-10},
     d = {150,-55},
     e = {180, },
     f = { ,-250},
     g = {150,-10},
     h = {100, },
     i = {210, },
     j = { ,-40},
     k = {110,-50},
     l = {240,-110},
     m = {80, },
     n = {115, },
     o = {155, },
     p = { , },
     q = {170,-40},
     r = {155,-40},
     s = {130, },
     t = {230,-10},
     u = {120, },
     v = {140,-25},
     w = {98,-20},
     x = {65,-40},
     y = {130,-20},
     z = {110,-80},
     0 = {170,-85},
     1 = {230,110},
     2 = {130,-70},
     3 = {140,-70},
     4 = {130,80},
     5 = {160, },
     6 = {175,-30},
     7 = {250,-150},
     8 = {130,-40},
     9 = {155,-80},
     . = { ,500},
    {,}= { ,450},
     : = { ,300},
     ; = { ,300},
     & = {130,30},
    \% = {180,50},
     * = {380,20},
     + = {180,200},
     @ = {180,10},
     ~ = {200,150},
     ( = {300, },    ) = {  ,70},
     / = {100,100},
     - = {500,300},
     \textendash       = {500,300},   \textemdash        = {400,170},
     \textquoteleft    = {800,200},   \textquoteright    = {800,-20},
     \textquotedblleft = {540,100},   \textquotedblright = {500,100}
   }

\begin{document}
\noindent\itshape
This is a small text. If jam is what you like, two fingers up,
or whatever. Under certain conditions you see that the left and
right margins flutter.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you think that your values are better and should be added to microtype: Send them the author of microtype.

Comment: @Ulrike: Thanks, I'll do that. (I'm not a professional typesetter, so I'm not sure if it's _good_, but I'm pretty sure that it's _better_ than before.)

Comment: @Ulrike: With the help of Robert Schlicht, I further improved the values (actually more than a year ago ...); the updated package has been available on tlcontrib for some time now.

Answer (score 17):

microtype has an optional argument that you can allow to shift the characters more to the right, e.g. `[factor=1300]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,picture}
\usepackage{microtype}
\textwidth=3.85cm
\begin{document}
\itshape\noindent\makebox(0,0){\put(\textwidth,-2cm){\line(0,-1){80}}}%
This is a small text. If jam is what you like, two fingers up,
or whatever. Under certain conditions you see that the left and
right margins flutter.
\end{document}
```

[image]

and here the output with optional arguments `[factor=1100,stretch=80]` for `microtype`

[image]

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks. The right margin is a lot better, but I'm more concerned about the _left_ margin. By the way, what optional argument do you mean? In your code there is none.

Comment: @Hendrik: I meant, you can increase it, see edited answer. The default of `factor` is 1000

Comment: @Herbert: Is this `factor` only about hanging punctuation? There the standard seems OK.

Comment: @Hendrik:  it is for the character protrusion. `microtype` has a lot of optional arguments.

Comment: @Herbert: I had a look at the manual and read a bit about protrusion. Did I get it right that the protrusion is set for each character individually? So for the left margin I'd have to adjust the settings?

Comment: @Hendrik: see file `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg`, there is a part for the itshape

Comment: @Herbert: Great, thanks! I didn't find this file on my system, but I did find `mt-cmr.cfg`, and playing with the values does help with the left margin, too. What I don't understand, though: If they do have correction values for all the capital letters there; why don't they have _better_ values? Who chose the values on which basis?

Comment: @Herbert: OK, `factor` didn't help, but I managed to improve the values in `mt-cmr.cfg`, and this gives the output I want. I still wonder why the values are chosen in the way they are.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I think using the Latin Modern fonts with [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) seems to be a better approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,microtype}

\textwidth=3.85cm
\begin{document}
\it\noindent
This is a small text. If jam is what you like, two fingers up,
or whatever. Under certain conditions you see that the left and
right margins flutter.
\end{document}
```

[image: microtype-version]

Comment: As a note, the most obvious change between the version in the question and my alternative is in line 3. That shows up best if you compare the two side-by-side. I know Hendrik doesn't like the left margin, but to me the right margin in the original is more visually-jarring (mainly because of where the full-stop ends up).