# SetProtrusion with helvetica on specific characters

Tags: pdftex, microtype, protrusion, helvetica

I am using a document with Helvetica from the `helvet` package. I would like dashes not to protrude into the left margin. However, when I use `SetProtrusion` protrusion is disabled entirely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{microtype}
% \LoadMicrotypeFile{helvet}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi a vel justo x  --- test --- a --- ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Edit: that is, if I add

```
\SetProtrusion{encoding = T1}{\textendash = {0,}, \textemdash = {0,}}
```

below `\usepackage{microtype}`

From the answer under [Modifying (i.e., partially overriding) microtype's character protrusion settings for specific characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123989/modifying-i-e-partially-overriding-microtypes-character-protrusion-settings) and looking at [section 5.7 of the manual](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/TLLATEST/texmf-dist/doc/latex/microtype/microtype.pdf) I figure I need to create a file `mt-helvet.cfg` file. I tried saving the `microtype.cfg` file as `mt-helvet.cfg` in my working directory, changing all protrusion settings on dashes to be 0 for the left margin; however, when I compile the document with `\LoadMicrotypeFile{helvet}` I get a document with no protrusion at all (i.e. identical to not loading `microtype`).

Comment: It might be helpful (just so we're all on the same page) if you could post your `mt-helvet.cfg` and the portions of the resulting `.log` file that deal with `microtype` generally.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/p5emK0Vm is the `mt-helvet.cfg` file. The `.log` files contains numerous warnings like `Package microtype Warning: Redefining protrusion set `all' on input line 51.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not base your font-specific configuration file on the *global* configuration file `microtype.cfg`, which is not supposed to be loaded twice (that's why you get all the warnings). Secondly, the name of the configuration file should be `mt-phv.cfg` (which is the name of the Helvetica font), not `mt-helvet.cfg` (which is just the package name). But thirdly, creating a font-specific configuration file is optional anyway, for a start it may be easier to change the settings directly in the preamble.

As a first step, you need to find out which settings are actually used for Helvetica. If you load `microtype` with the `verbose` option, you will find this in the `log` file (near the end):

```
Package microtype Info: Setting up font `T1/phv/m/n/10' on input line 14.
Package microtype Info: ... Loading protrusion list `T1-default'.
```

So you know now that you want to change the settings `T1-default` (which are generic, as specific settings for Helvetica don't exist). These settings are defined in `microtype.cfg`, which is always loaded by the package; therefore, you do not need to load any other file, but can change the settings right away:

```
\SetProtrusion
   [ name     = T1-phv,      % the name is optional
     load     = T1-default ] % first load `T1-default` settings
   { encoding = T1,
     family   = phv }        % use for Helvetica family
   {
     \textendash = {0, }, \textemdash = {0, }  % cancel out left protrusion
   }
```

If you don't want to clutter your preamble, you may also put the above in a file `mt-phv.cfg`, which will then be loaded automatically, but as I said, this is optional.