# SetProtrusion of microtype package doesn't have any effect

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, protrusion

I am trying to change or disable protrusion for specific characters. However, it doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

[image: emdash protrusion]

I use [Charis SIL font](http://software.sil.org/charis/download/) and for now I am trying to disable endash and emdash protrusion. I am compiling with LuaLaTeX 1.0.4 (TeXLive 2017).

```
\documentclass[final,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Charis SIL}
\usepackage[factor=1000]{microtype}
\SetProtrusion
{ 
encoding = {*}
family = {*}
% family = Charis SIL
}
{ 
\textemdash = {,0},
\textendash = {,0},
% \textemdash = {,2000}, % Setting protrusion to bigger value doesn't change anything either
% \textendash = {,2000}, %
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Uta purus quis.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit aemet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Utea purous---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit aemet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Utea purous\textemdash

Lorem ipsum dolor sit aemet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Utean purousa\textendash

\end{document}
```

For my test case, I have tried to either disable or increase protrusion for these 2 characters, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Side question: is this possible to enable protrusion only for specific characters? For example, I would want to have protrusion disabled for all fonts in all encodings, with exception of period, comma and semicolon.

Comment: There is a comma missing in your code after `encoding = {*}`. Some info about how to override settings are also here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124032/2388

Comment: I added comma now, but it did not change the result. I saw that answer before asking my question, but I have no idea what name to use with ``LoadMicrotypeFile`` and whether it is actually required.

Comment: When I add the command and use the 2000 values I see changes even without LoadMicrotypeFile.

Comment: I meant "when I add the comma".

Comment: Btw: When using the zero values the endash sticks in the margin not because of protrusion but because of an overfull line. You can see the warning in the log.

Comment: put `\LoadMicrotypeFile{CharisSIL}` before the `\SetProtrusion` command.

Comment: @Robert Thanks a lot: it wasn't working for me without ``\LoadMicrotypeFile{CharisSIL}``. I noticed that ``\SetProtrusion`` from my MWE (with comma added) together with ``\LoadMicrotypeFile`` disables protrusion for characters not defined in ``\SetProtrusion`` command. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: @Robert In other words, should ``\SetProtrusion`` used together with ``LoadMicrotypeFile`` overwrite default settings for specified font set? I expected that only characters defined in ``\SetProtrusion`` would have their default values overwritten by whatever I specify.

Comment: Yes, if you create new settings, the old settings will be overwritten. You can, however, as is explained in the answer @UlrikeFischer linked to (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124032/7674), `load` settings, which you can then modify or extend.