# hanging punctuation with microtype and luaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, typography, microtype

I want to get [this style](http://www.artlebedev.com/mandership/120/) of hanging punctuation:
[image: Hanging punctuation]

> Quotation marks `«...»   „...“`, brackets `(...) [...] {...}` and
>   bullets are put beyond the left margin.
>
> Quotation marks, brackets,
>   periods, and commas are set outside the right margin. Hyphens (both in compound words and between the syllables
>   of a word that’s divided at the end of a line) should not fall outside
>   the margin full-length, but rather be hung one third or half of their
>   length.

I try to achieve this by using the `\SetProtrusion` command according to the manual ([page 12](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf)):

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic,Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setromanfont{Charis SIL}[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setsansfont{PT Sans}[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmonofont{PT Mono}[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,final,babel=true,factor=2000]{microtype}
\SetProtrusion 
{encoding = *}
{
    \textquotedblleft = {4000, },
    \textquotedblright = { ,4000},
    . = { , 4000}
    « = {4000, },
    » = { ,4000},
    ( = {4000, },
    ) = { ,4000}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\enquote{Окончательная машинописная рукопись основана на отредактированном третьем варианте и, после того как она готова, ее \enquote{читают} и правят, и правят заново.
Приблизительно через два) года после начала работы (два рабочих года! Они могут быть. намного длиннее двух календарных лет...) книга отсылается в} издательство.\\
«Окончательная машинописная рукопись  основана на отредактированном третьем варианте и, после того как она готова, ее (читают и правят, и правят заново.
Приблизительно через два) года после начала работы (два рабочих года! Они могут быть. намного длиннее двух календарных лет...) книга отсылается в» издательство....
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work:

[image]

(If it matters, I use LuaLaTeX from MikTeX on Windows 7)

Comment: The `fontspec` commands take the optional argument *after* the name of the font, e.g., `\setmainfont{Charis SIL}[Ligatures=TeX]`.

Comment: probably not relevant, but the hyphens in the second example look very narrow, and splitting them in half wouldn't have much effect.

Comment: @Manuel -- For the record: both syntactic formats (optional arguments before or after the mandatory argument) of `fontspec`'s font-related directives work *equally well*.

Comment: @Mico It lead me to a problem in the past :) But I still don't get your point, really. Both work equally well, yeah, one is the official way, and the other one is just for compatibility. I don't see the point of reminding that both work, I think it's better to recommend the official way. (To me it's similar —not equal— as if someone reminded that `{\bf this}` gives bold font instead of just recommending `\textbf{this}`.)

Comment: @Manuel - My point is that there's no problem pointing out that the optional arguments *can* come after rather than before the mandatory argument *if* you also point out that both orderings produce identical results -- and will continue to do so indefinitely. This is quite different from the status of TeX macros such as `\bf`, `\sl`, and `\it`. The `fontspec` manual (see esp subsection 5.5, "Miscellaneous font selecting details") takes care to point out that "backwards compatibility has been preserved".

Comment: @Mco To me that sentence you quoted, “backwards compatibility has been preserved”, completely answers this doubt: no reason to mention that old behaviour at all. But it seems so clear to me that I think I'm missing something (may be a translation issue to my language – or that I don't understand English as my mother tongue). I will take this to the chat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your settings are never applied because in the first argument to `\SetProtrusion` you only specify the encoding. `microtype` will always try to load the best matching settings, and since settings for Charis SIL exist, they will be applied instead. Drawing from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11435/7674), you can overwrite settings by first loading the configuration file and then redefining these settings:

```
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,final,babel=true]{microtype} % default factor (1000)
\LoadMicrotypeFile{CharisSIL}
\SetProtrusion
   [ name = Charis-default ]
   { }
   {
    \textquotedblleft = {1000, },
    \textquotedblright = { ,1000},
    \quotedblbase = {1000, }, % = „
    . = { , 1000}, % there was a comma missing here
   {,} = { , 1000}, % this comma needs to be masked 
    « = {1000, },
    » = { ,1000},
    ( = {1000, },
    ) = { ,1000},
    - = { ,500}
   }
```

For the other shapes, you can then simply load these settings:

```
\SetProtrusion
   [ name = Charis-it,
     load = Charis-default ]
   {}{}
\SetProtrusion
   [ name = Charis-sc,
     load = Charis-default ]
   {}{}
```

(I must say that I find these settings weird, since they are contrary to the idea that microtypographical tweaks should be discreet and not jump out at the reader – as elaborated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82637/7674))