# Italic Correction for Linux Libertine Font

Tags: fonts, spacing, italic-correction, libertine

I was looking for a new font for the manuals of my LaTeX packages and found the [*Linux Libertine*](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/libertine/) most pleasing. However it seems that it **doesn't support italic correction** (yet).

I assume that a font normally defines the correct italic correction for every character, but I would settle if *any* extra amount would be added after italic text. At the moment a text used in `\meta{...}` hits the closing angle symbol because of the missing italic correction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
(\textit{X})

\def\metastyle{\textit}
\def\meta#1{{\metastyle {\ensuremath \langle #1\/\ensuremath \rangle }}}
\meta{X}
\end{document}
```

I had the idea of the very quick and very dirty trick `\let\/\,` which works in this case, but not for general `\textit{...}` uses. (`\/` is for explicit italic correction and `\,` adds a small space, IIRC half a normal space)

Checking the definition of `\textit` revealed that it finally uses `\@@italiccorr` which is let to the original `\/` *primitive*.
Defining this macro as well to `\,` seems to add the small space also on other places where it is not wanted.

Is there a better way to get some decent italic correction for this font? It doesn't have to be perfect, just better then the current one (i.e. literally "better than nothing").

Comment: Can you please give an example of a case where "defining this macro as well to `\,` seems to add the small space also on other places where it is not wanted"?

Comment: @Hendrik: I researched this now and apparently `\@@italiccorr` is placed *before* and *after* every `\textXX` macro, so redefining it to a fixed space is not good.

Comment: @Martin: And what about redefining `\/`?

Comment: @Hendrik: This works only when `\/` is used explicitly. The problem is that `\/` is a primitive and `\@@italiccorr` is `\let` to it, so changing it afterwards doesn't affect it.

Comment: @Hendrik: Checking on `\/` again revealed that it produces a zero kerning in non-italic fonts (because the italic correction in them is 0) and is therefore save to be used before and after the normal `\textXX` macros. A manual redefinition doesn't know if italic correction should be applied or not :-(

Comment: In pdfTeX you can't change the italic correction after a font is loaded. Probably you need to create a virtual font or switch to LuaTeX.

Comment: Further to what Philipp says, I understand that in Luatex you can dynamically change the italic correction of each character in a font using the structure described in chapter 7 of [the Luatex manual](http://www.luatex.org/svn/trunk/manual/luatexref-t.pdf).  @Philipp: maybe you'd like to post your comment as an answer?  Maybe with a pointer on how to construct virtual fonts: I have no idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try it with hacking into LaTeX's `\check@nocorr@`. Remove the left correction and `\let` the italic correction to `\,` (or another suitable amount). This may have issues, but for your code it works. I have assumed that you use Linux Libertine throughout your document; otherwise you'll have to make the hack local.

Before:  [image]       After:  [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\makeatletter
\def \check@nocorr@ #1#2\nocorr#3\@nil {%
  \let \check@icl \@empty                    %%% removed left correction
  \def \check@icr {\ifvmode \else \aftergroup \maybe@ic \fi}%
  \def \reserved@a {\nocorr}%
  \def \reserved@b {#1}%
  \def \reserved@c {#3}%
  \ifx \reserved@a \reserved@b
    \ifx \reserved@c \@empty
      \let \check@icl \@empty
    \else
      \let \check@icl \@empty
      \let \check@icr \@empty
    \fi
  \else
    \ifx \reserved@c \@empty
    \else
      \let \check@icr \@empty
    \fi
  \fi
}
\let\/\,
\let\@@italiccorr\/
\makeatother
\begin{document}
(\textit{X})

\def\metastyle{\textit}
\def\meta#1{{\metastyle {\ensuremath \langle #1\/\ensuremath \rangle }}}
\meta{X}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Hendrik! I will test it as soon I have time (busy week). I'm using `lmodern` for the `tt` font at the moment to get bold tt in `listings`, but this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I tested the code now and for most situation it works. I added a test if `#1` is `f` or `g` which requires some left italic correction. It's not perfect but a suitable workaround. I'm looking forward till they add real italic correction to this font!

Comment: @Martin: I'm glad that it works. Just to let you know, TeXnically speaking there's no such thing as "left italic correction"; this is discussed to some extent in [this answer of mine and it's first comments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/space-between-emphasized-word-and-parenthesis/4189#4189).

Comment: @Martin: Can you please temporarily "unaccept" this answer? It seems that yesterday [they implemented something so that I should be notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer) - I'd love to test this!

Comment: @Martin: Thanks - the test failed miserably; if I hadn't asked you to unaccept, I'd have no idea from the dropdown menu that the unaccept was for this answer here. I left comments on that meta.SO post.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Two years later the code of Linux Libertine did not improve yet, as far as I know. Could you please post your amended version for f and g and whatever?