# Microtype and quote environment leads to different indent of first line

Tags: spacing, punctuation, quoting, microtype

When the `microtype` package is loaded a `quote` environment which starts with punctuation marks is inconsistent "indented". The first line in the following minimal example is unaffected, i.e. at the same place as without the package, but the next two lines are pushed to the left. I realize that it is a *feature* of the `microtype` package to push punctuation marks into the margin, but here it looks quite ugly because it isn't consistent. The first line is most likely different because of the included `\item` in `\begin{quote}`.

Is there a way to get the indention consistent? Can I temporarly disable this feature of `microtype` just for this environment? I'm having such code in some package manuals where some verbatim code lines which start with "punctuation" like `{` inside a `quote` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{quote}
    ()\\
    ()\\
    ()
\end{quote}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Originally I thought this has to do with the missing italic correction of the originally used font (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13340/italic-correction-for-linux-libertine-font) but after minimizing the file it turns out that is font independent.

Comment: A local `\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}` works for me.

Comment: @Andrey: This is what I was looking for! Please add it as answer. I don't know the `microtype` very well and didn't even know that this feature is called `protrusion`. It's not that obvious for an non-native speaker.

Comment: I'd say that it's only a workaround to locally disable the protrusion. For your use case it might be OK, but in general it's not good to have inconsistent protrusion.

Comment: @Hendrik: I agree, that it the reason I didn't accepted Andrey's answer yet. I still think the `\item` in the `quote` is the clue. The protrusion doesn't work there.

Comment: Just a note that microtype now fixes this automatically (since v3.0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The suggested solution from the author of microtype is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\protrudeleft[1]{%
    {\everypar{}%
     \setbox\z@\vbox{\noindent#1}%
     \vbadness=\@M
     \splittopskip=\z@
     \global\setbox\z@=\vsplit\z@ to \baselineskip
     \unvbox\z@ \global\setbox\z@=\lastbox
    }%
    \ifhbox\z@
      \leavevmode
      \kern\leftmarginkern\z@
    \fi
    #1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text
\begin{quote}
    \protrudeleft()\\
    ()\\
    ()
\end{quote}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text
\end{document}
```

Attention: You will perhaps have to put the argument of \protrudeleft in braces if is not a like here a simple character.

Comment: The drawback of this solution is that you have to remember to put the `\protrudeleft`. What would interest me: I'm not too sure about my own answer, does it also have disadvantages? It would be great if you can tell me.

Comment: Your environment will not work as expected if the content contains lists. Include e.g. an itemize in the middle and see what happens. Also the protrusion problem affects all lists, e.g. an itemize and `\protrudeleft` helps there too.

Comment: @Ulrike: Ah, I see, thanks. Could `microtype` solve this by patching the `list` environment so that it automatically starts with `\protrudeleft` if appropriate?

Comment: Robert sent once a patch for the verse environment (in comp.text.tex, "character protruding and verses"), but said that it is rather fragile, that problems are to be expected and that "pdftex really needs a primitive to simulate line beginnings/ends".

Comment: "pdftex really needs a primitive to simulate line beginnings/ends": Yes, indeed, this sounds like the Way to Go.

Comment: Ulrike, @Hendrik: I found this feature request for pdfTeX about simulated line beginnings/ends: http://sarovar.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=743&group_id=106&atid=496

Comment: @MartinScharrer Do you know if it has moved elsewhere? I (eventually) get an empty page at that address.

Comment: I stumbled across the exact problem described here. Is there meanwhile an accepted solution without a drawback? Can I redefine my quote environment to patch the first indended line?

Comment: @johnny7 this answer is 11 years old. And no you shouldn't use it  (and with a currenty microtype it shouldn't be needed, it does that now automatically).

Comment: I was going to ask the exact same question and was happy to see it had already been asked before (not only here, but also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93992/protrusion-issue-pdftex-bug-microtype-bug-or-latex-bug?noredirect=1&lq=1) for example). But with TeX Live 2021 the problem with different indentation of the first quote line still stands for me and I haven't yet found a solution. I redefined: A workaround is to begin the quote environment with `\par` but that has unwanted side effects (different vertical spaces).

Comment: @johnny7 the example in the question above works fine for me in a up-to-date texlive 2021.

Comment: I redefined `\renewenvironment{quote}
{\list{}{\leftmargin0.5cm \rightmargin0cm}
\item\relax\fontsize{9.8pt}{11.4pt}\selectfont}
{\endlist}`

Comment: @johnny7 don't ask new questions in a comment. If you changed something ask a new question.

Answer (score 16):

Main [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) features can be enabled or disabled on the fly using the `\microtypesetup` command. In this case we need to locally disable character protrusion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newenvironment{example}{\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}%
  \begin{quote}}{\end{quote}}

\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{example}
    ()\\
    ()\\
    ()
\end{example}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

This will, of course, have effect on all characters, be it `()` or any other symbol. An interesting task would be to *selectively* disable this feature if it should be kept enabled for symbols other than `()`.

Answer (score 9):

I'd define my own `microtype`-safe environment to consistently have protrusion everywhere. Adjust the `3em` to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newenvironment{mtsafequote}
    {\par\bgroup\leftskip=3em\rightskip=3em\noindent\ignorespaces}
    {\par\egroup\noindent}
\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{mtsafequote}
    ()\\
    ()\\
    ()
\end{mtsafequote}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Henderik, for my very specific application this seems to be the way to go. I [added something like this](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/general/changeset/2326/ydoc/dev/ydoc_desc_sty.dtx) to `ydoc` now. As Ulrike states this seems to note suite for general quote like environments.

Answer (score 6):

Martin, here is the kernel of what is needed. I think you are better qualified than I am to wrap this up into a nicely robust redefined `quote` environment (or maybe fix it at the `list`, `\item` level):

```
\begin{quote}
    \quitvmode\kern\dimexpr-0.001em*\the\lpcode\font`(\relax()\\
    ()\\
    ()
\end{quote}
```