# How to vertically center content of page without makeup in ConTeXt?

Tags: vertical-alignment, context, context-mkiv

I need to vertically center the content of page, content is forced to be on a separate page (delimeted with `\page` command).

```
previous page content

\page 

this content must be verticaly centered on it's page.

\page 

next page
```

placing `\vfill` after first `\page` does nothing. I need to center content without using makeup, because makeup removes page numbering, but I need to typeset this page as usual.

Comment: ``\dontleavehmode \vfill foo bar \vfill``.

Comment: That works! You can post your answer to get score.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When entering a page in normal typesetting mode, Context

1. is in vertical mode, and
2. will gobble all skips that follow immediately so as to align the top
   of the first line of the text body appropriately.

For this reason, inserting a vertical skip has no effect at the top of
a page.

To work around this behavior you need to force TeX into horizontal
mode, which you can do by

1. inserting horizontal material, for instance a strut, or
2. terminating vertical mode explicitly, which is usually done by means
   of the [`\dontleavehmode`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/3234906ac7cb4eac2077af3dff2b3db452514cd0:/tex/context/base/syst-aux.mkiv#l5851)
   directive (the Context synonym for the
   [`\quitvmode`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13769/14066)
   primitive), or alternatively the lesser known
   [`\leavevmode`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/3234906ac7cb4eac2077af3dff2b3db452514cd0:/tex/context/base/syst-ini.mkiv#l437) [0].

The idiomatic solution would look like this:

```
\starttext
  \dontleavehmode \vfill
  foo
  \vfill
\stoptext
```

[image: Example output]

Thus, if you intend to vertically center a page without using makeups,
you could define an environment as follows (thanks to /u/Aditya for the
suggestion):

```
\definestartstop [centeredpage] [
  before=\dontleavehmode \vfill,
  after=\vfill,
]

\starttext
  \startcenteredpage
    foo
  \stopcenteredpage
\stoptext
```

On a related note, what you are asking for can actually be achieved
conveniently by tweaking the
[options to `\setupmakeup`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/8eaeb46048e8d1a3bcfc18d5b87bae71216a3cf7:/tex/context/base/page-mak.mkvi#l170).
The key settings are `pagestate` whose value is passed to an
implicit `\setuppagenumber`, as well as `headerstate` and
`footerstate` that govern the behavior of running heads and footers,
respectively.
To make headers and footers appear on the makeup, and to prevent the
page numbering from ignoring that page, these options need to be set to
*start* (they default to *stop*).
For example:

```
\definemakeup [centeredpage]
\setupmakeup [centeredpage] [
  pagestate=start,
  top=\vfill,
  bottom=\vfill,
  headerstate=start,
  footerstate=start,
  page=yes,
]

\setupheadertexts [dummy header]
\setupfootertexts [dummy footer] [{\getnumber [userpage]}]

\starttext
  text on page before
  \startcenteredpagemakeup
    \input ward
  \stopcenteredpagemakeup
  text on page after
\stoptext
```

[image: Example with makeup]

[0] For a discussion of `\leavevmode` vs. `\dontleavehmode` /
`\quitvmode` see
[this post by Taco on the Pdftex list](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2004-July/000674.html).

Comment: It may be better to define a startstop environment for this rather than entering the raw commands in the text

Comment: @Aditya That’d amount to some makeshift version of makeups, wouldn’t it?

Comment: Yes. But my comment was motivated by the idea that **all** markup in a document should be semantic markup. The OP probably want a dedication page (or copyright page), so the markup should show that.

Comment: @Aditya I incorporated your suggestion into the answer, though it’s not really *semantic* because OP didn’t give the purpose of the centered content.