# How to correct vertical alignment for large text sizes in ConTeXt

Tags: vertical-alignment, context

I want to vertically center the content of all pages. I followed the approach in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155734/91605, but alignment becomes increasingly skewed from actual center when as the body font size grows. This happens no matter whether there is a single line of text or many. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
\setupbodyfont[100pt]
\showframe

\starttext

\dontleavehmode\vfill
text
\vfill

\stoptext
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `align=lohi` option of `\framed`:

```
\setuppagenumbering[location=]
\setupbodyfont[100pt]
\showframe
\showboxes

\starttext

\dontleavehmode
\framed[height=\textheight, width=\textwidth, align={lohi}]
{text}

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Any idea why this is necessary?