# vertically center all slides in ConTeXt with minimal setups

Tags: vertical-alignment, context

I would like to emulate beamer's centred framed behaviour in my ConTeXt presentation. Thanks to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155522/how-to-vertically-center-content-of-page-without-makeup-in-context), I figured out how to have my (sub)section titles centred. I am also using a makeup for my main title.
My main text wasn't vertically centred however. Today, I realized I could use a custom framed environment.

Here is how I get my vertically centred presentations now (all the setups are in an environment, I past the relevant item in the MWE for convenience):

```
\setuppapersize[S5]
\setupbodyfont[18pt]
\setuplayout[topspace=1cm,backspace=1.5cm,
   width=14.5cm,height=11cm,%margin=0cm,
   footer=0cm,header=0cm]    
\definelayout[titre][topspace=0cm,backspace=1.5cm,
   width=15cm,height=11cm,
   footer=0cm,header=0cm]
\definemakeup[titre]     
\setuphead[title][
   alternative=middle,%titre centré sur la ligne
   before={\leavevmode \vfill},after={\vfill \page},
   style=\tfd]
\setuphead[section][align=lohi,
   before={\page\leavevmode \vfill},after={\vfill},
   style=\tfc,conversion=I,
   numbercommand=\groupedcommand{}{~)},%) après le numéro
   align={flushleft, nothyphenated, verytolerant}]    
\defineframedtext
     [Diapo]
     [frame=no,
     before={\page\leavevmode\vfill},after={\vfill}]

\starttext
\startmakeup[titre]
\starttitle[title={Un test}]
\stopmakeup

\startsection[title={Bonjour}]
  \startDiapo
      Hello world!
   \stopDiapo
\stopsection
\stoptitle
\stoptext
```

Here is my question : how can I minimize those setups? Especially:

- is there any way to get my texts centred without framing them (`\start/stopDiapo`)?
- I couldn't find any global command that gives a vertically centred layout. Is there a way to do it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Makeup environment

The best method to center the content of each frame is the use of a `makeup` environment. With the `top` and `bottom` you can control the vertical alignment of the text and with the `align` key you can change the horizontal alignment.

```
\setuppapersize [S3] [S3,doublewide]

\showframe [page]

\setuparranging [2SIDE]

\starttext

First page

\startstandardmakeup [align=middle,pagestate=start,headerstate=start]
Second page
\stopstandardmakeup

\stoptext
```

[image]

## Section headers

When you use the environment form of section header get additional keys to insert commands before and after the content of each section.

When you have a header without content (e.g. for the title page) you can use the regular form and pass the title as argument to the command.

```
\setuppapersize [S3] [S3,doublewide]

\showframe [page]

\setuparranging [2SIDE]

\define[1]\ShowKey
  {\par
   \leftaligned{\tttf [key: #1]}%
   \par}

\setuphead
  [subject]
  [       before=\ShowKey{before},
           after=\ShowKey{after},
   beforesection=\ShowKey{beforesection},
   insidesection=\ShowKey{insidesection},
    aftersection=\ShowKey{aftersection}]

\setupheader [state=stop]

\starttext

\subject {First subject}

\page

\startsubject [title={Second subject}]
Subject content
\stopsubject

\stoptext
```

[image]

## Combination of both mechanism

You can combine the `makeup` environment with the environment form of section headers and use the `insidesection` and `aftersection` keys to center the content of each section.

```
\setuppapersize [S3]

\definehead [frametitle]   [title]
\definehead [framesection] [section]

\definemakeup
  [section]
  [pagestate=start,
   align=middle]

\definemakeup
  [frame]
  [pagestate=start,
   align=middle]

\setuphead
  [frametitle]
  [align=middle,
   before=\startsectionmakeup,
   after=\stopsectionmakeup]

\setuphead
  [framesection]
  [align=middle,
   before=\startsectionmakeup,
   after=\stopsectionmakeup,
   insidesection=\startframemakeup,
   aftersection=\stopframemakeup]

\starttext

\frametitle{Un test}

\startframesection[title={Bonjour}]
  Hello world!
\stopframesection

\stoptext
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you edit your example to have "Hello world" vertically centered and justified? Thanks.

Comment: I suggested an edit for your post that makes it closer to my MWE. Anyway, could you tell me what the key `pagestate` stands for? Wiki does not explain it AFAIK.

Comment: @sztruks As I wrote you can use the `align` key to change the horizontal alignment, by default you get justified text. With the `pagestate` key you can control whether `makeup` pages are included or excluded (which is the default setting) from the page counter.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood what you wrote about `align`. One last question: I understand makeups are one page-only output. Am I right? `\pages` are ignored within them, which seems consistent to the wiki makeup definition.

Comment: Yes, the `makeup` environment creates a unbreakable block which is placed on a separate page. You can use the environment for standalone pages like a title page.