# unpleasent character protrusion using microtype, biblatex and block=nbpar

Tags: biblatex, microtype

Using `microtype` together with `biblatex`'s `entrysets` and `block=nbpar` options leads to an unpleasent result. The left bracket of (a) is moved too much to the right. (b) and (c) are less affected by the protrustion. What can I do about it except disabling microtype?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,subentry,block=nbpar]{biblatex}

\usepackage{microtype}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler text \cite{stdmodel}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is similar to the one raised in [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13666/4483) related to `csquotes`. Taking [Lev Bishop's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13702/4483), you can incorporate the needed left protrusion for the first subentry into the `set` driver originally defined in `numeric.bbx`:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \quitvmode\kern\dimexpr-0.001em*\the\lpcode\font`(\relax%
  \entryset
    {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
       {\printfield[bibentrysetcount]{entrysetcount}%
        \printunit*{\addnbspace}}
       {}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}
```